# How to print third column to last column?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, multiple-columns

I'm trying to remove the first two columns (of which I'm not interested in) from a DbgView log file. I can't seem to find an example that prints from column 3 onwards until the end of the line. Note that each line has variable number of columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

...or a simpler solution: `cut -f 3- INPUTFILE`  just add the correct delimiter (-d) and you got the same effect.

Comment: Note that this only works if the delimiter is exactly the same between all columns... For example, you can't use cut with a delimiter like \d+. (That I know of.)

Comment: When question is titled awk it is inappropriate to accept answer other than awk. What if people need it for awk scripts? This answer should've just been a comment.

Comment: @SyaZ: Normally I'd agree, but with the amount of 'gratuitous awk' going on this board, I thought it's needed to show an alternative way of doing the task.  Wouldn't you be thankful if someone showed you a simpler and quicker way to do the same task?  Maybe the poster thought awk is the only way to do this because of number of 'not incorrect, but certainly improvable upon' answers to other questions?

Comment: That's what the comment is for. Accept the best awk answer and provide better non-awk suggestions on comments. If people start posting answers that don't exactly answer questions, it will be annoying when searching (in my case).

Comment: Not only delimiter have to be the same between all columns, but there have to be EXACTLY ONE delimiter character between columns. So if you are dealing with programs that align their output with delimiters, it is better to use awk.

Comment: why do you need a dash after 3?

Comment: 3 by itself is print field number 3.  3- is print field 3 and all the fields after it.

Comment: @ZachWily, @sknaumov, the Unix way to mitigate this \s+ delimiter issue is by piping through `tr -s '[:blank:]' ' '` beforehand [[source](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-09/msg00165.html)].

Comment: Just a quick update, I ran a bunch of the awk solutions from this thread and they all ran a bit around 65-78 seconds (2.2GB file), while my simple 'cut' version ran in 6 seconds.  I win ;)

Comment: Reran the awk scripts using mawk instead of gawk.  Runtime is 12-13secs.  Cut still wins on speed.

Comment: The original title asked for an answer using Awk so, for this reason, I agree that this shouldn't have been given the tick. However, I don't feel tags should limit the answers as often the asker is just guessing how to tag to get relevant people looking at their question. It's not a requirement for how you must answer the question. The question is in cases where it sets a limiation.

Comment: This doesn't do anything on my Debian 11

Answer (score 132):

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)print $i}'
```

Comment: awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)print $i}' be more compact. :)

Comment: Thanks, lh3. I was just copying and pasting for the gawk manual. :)

Comment: I think that you can do something like this `awk 'NF >= 3'`

Comment: this fails with multiple lines, each column is trated as a new line when printed iwth print

Comment: @user2571881 that is only printing for me results that have fields equal to or larger than 3, anot just the the remainder AFTEr those 3

Comment: Splitted output is getting displayed with `newline separator`. Does not work for me.

Comment: To address the splitted output issue, I propose this solution: `awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)printf $i""FS ; print ""}'` (`printf`will not print the newline char while `print ""` will add newline after the other fields has been printed)

Comment: Or: `echo $(seq 1 10) | awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf $i FS}'`, which gives: `3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

Comment: It adds each column on a different line. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130247/3154883

Answer (score 130):

```
awk '{ print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }'
```

solution found here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/awk-print-field-to-end-and-character-count-179078/

Comment: I'm kind of late for this, but this won't work for records in which the first or second field is equal to the third (e.g., 3 2 3 4 5)

Comment: printing an internal range is also possible: ```
# from $3 (included) to $6 (excluded); 
echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}{ print substr($0, index($0,$3), length($0)-index($0,$6)-1) }'; # gives
3,4,5```

Answer (score 40):

**Jonathan Feinberg**'s answer prints each field on a separate line. You could use `printf` to rebuild the record for output on the same line, but you can also just move the fields a jump to the left.

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF-2; i++) $i = $(i+2); NF-=2; print}' logfile
```

Comment: Be aware, that this only works for Gnu awk, decrementing `NF` is not allowed by POSIX.

Comment: @kvantour: It works in gawk, mawk, MacOS awk (nawk?). POSIX appears to be silent on whether `NF` can be decremented.

Comment: It is one of these funny [dark corners of awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450603/whats-allowed-to-do-with-nf-in-an-awk-code-block-or-function).

Answer (score 24):

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' file
```

NB: this method will leave "blanks" in 1,2,3 fields but not a problem if you just want to look at output.

Comment: Trail that command with ` | sed s/^\ *// | column -t` to strip leading spaces and align the remaining columns

Comment: What does the last `1` mean? which keyword should I search with `awk`?

Comment: @Itachi see example 1 of http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Comment: @Nathan you solve this issue as `{$1=$2=$3="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1`

Comment: This is really useful for weeding out a few unnecessary columns in the middle (while still grabbing to the end)! Thanks @ghostdog74

Answer (score 19):

If you want to print the columns after the 3rd for example in the same line, you can use:

```
awk '{for(i=3; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i; print ""}'
```

For example:

```
Mar 09:39 20180301_123131.jpg
Mar 13:28 20180301_124304.jpg
Mar 13:35 20180301_124358.jpg
Feb 09:45 Cisco_WebEx_Add-On.dmg
Feb 12:49 Docker.dmg
Feb 09:04 Grammarly.dmg
Feb 09:20 Payslip 10459 %2828-02-2018%29.pdf
```

It will print:

```
20180301_123131.jpg
20180301_124304.jpg
20180301_124358.jpg
Cisco_WebEx_Add-On.dmg
Docker.dmg
Grammarly.dmg
Payslip 10459 %2828-02-2018%29.pdf
```

As we can see, the payslip even with space, shows in the correct line.

Comment: This is excellent, except I have a problem with $NF being excluded. When I set the condition (<=NF) I get the last field but the first character of the first field is chopped off. Am I misunderstanding something in terms of functionality?

Comment: Looks like my problem is that ^M is stuck to the end of the last column. Don't see how to remove it.

Answer (score 9):

What about following line:

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print}' file
```

Based on @ghostdog74 suggestion. Mine should behave better when you filter lines, i.e.:

```
awk '/^exim4-config/ {$1=""; print }' file
```

Comment: Short & simple. Could also pipe & add `sed 's/\s\+//g'` at the end of the command to trim leading spaces

Answer (score 8):

```
awk -v m="\x0a" -v N="3" '{$N=m$N ;print substr($0, index($0,m)+1)}'
```

This chops what is before the given field nr., N, and prints all the rest of the line, including field nr.N and maintaining the original spacing (it does not reformat). It doesn't mater if the string of the field appears also somewhere else in the line, which is the problem with daisaa's answer.

Define a function:

```
fromField () { 
awk -v m="\x0a" -v N="$1" '{$N=m$N; print substr($0,index($0,m)+1)}'
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$ echo "  bat   bi       iru   lau bost   " | fromField 3
iru   lau bost   
$ echo "  bat   bi       iru   lau bost   " | fromField 2
bi       iru   lau bost
```

Output maintains everything, including trailing spaces

Works well for files where '/n' is the record separator so you don't have that new-line char inside the lines. If you want to use it with other record separators then use:

```
awk -v m="\x01" -v N="3" '{$N=m$N ;print substr($0, index($0,m)+1)}'
```

for example. Works well with almost all files as long as they don't use hexadecimal char nr. 1 inside the lines.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '{a=match($0, $3); print substr($0,a)}'
```

First you find the position of the start of the third column. 
With substr you will print the whole line ($0) starting at the position(in this case a) to the end of the line.

Answer (score 5):

The following awk command prints the last N fields of each line and at the end of the line prints a new line character:

```
awk '{for( i=6; i<=NF; i++ ){printf( "%s ", $i )}; printf( "\n"); }'
```

Find below an example that lists the content of the /usr/bin directory and then holds the last 3 lines and then prints the last 4 columns of each line using awk:

```
$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/ | tail -3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14736 Jan 14  2014 bcomps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10480 Jan 14  2014 acyclic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    35868448 May 22  2014 skype

$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/ | tail -3 | awk '{for( i=6; i<=NF; i++ ){printf( "%s ", $i )}; printf( "\n"); }'
Jan 14 2014 bcomps 
Jan 14 2014 acyclic 
May 22 2014 skype
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane 'splice @F,0,2; print join " ",@F' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the perl code

`splice @F,0,2` cleanly removes columns 0 and 1 from the @F array

`join " ",@F` joins the elements of the @F array, using a space in-between each element

If your input file is comma-delimited, rather than space-delimited, use `-F, -lane`

---

Python solution:

`python -c "import sys;[sys.stdout.write(' '.join(line.split()[2:]) + '\n') for line in sys.stdin]" < file`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can easily accomplish the same effect using a regular expression. Assuming the separator is a space, it would look like:

```
awk '{ sub(/[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +/, ""); print }'
```

Comment: I'd avoid regex. It's probably slower and easier to accidentally mess up.

Comment: It shorten it like this: `awk '{ sub(/([^ ]+ +){2}/, ""); print }'` which takes the pattern two times away.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print ""}{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)printf $i" "}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here, but none of the above seemed to work.  Try this, using printf, inserts spaces between each.  I chose to not have newline at the end.

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) printf("%s ",  $i) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for (i=4; i<=NF; i++)printf("%c", $i); printf("\n");}'
```

prints records starting from the 4th field to the last field in the same order they were in the original file

Comment: sorry, this was not quite correct answer. it is too specific, but I do not know how to delete it

Answer (score 1):

In Bash you can use the following syntax with positional parameters:

```
while read -a cols; do echo ${cols[@]:2}; done < file.txt
```

Learn more: [Handling positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) at Bash Hackers Wiki

Answer (score 0):

If its only about ignoring the first two fields and if you don't want a space when masking those fields (like some of the answers above do) :

```
awk '{gsub($1" "$2" ",""); print;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1=$2=""}1' FILENAME | sed 's/\s\+//g'
```

First two columns are cleared, `sed` removes leading spaces.

Answer (score -2):

In AWK columns are called fields, hence NF is the key

all rows:

```
awk -F '<column separator>' '{print $(NF-2)}' <filename>
```

first row only:

```
awk -F '<column separator>' 'NR<=1{print $(NF-2)}' <filename>
```