# Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last

Tags: linux, shell, awk, cygwin

This line worked until I had whitespace in the second field:

```
svn status | grep '\!' | gawk '{print $2;}' > removedProjs
```

Is there a way to have `awk` print everything in `$2` or greater?  (`$3`, `$4`.. until we don't have any more columns?)

I'm doing this in a Windows environment with Cygwin.

Comment: As an aside, the [`grep | awk` is an antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) -- you want `awk '/!/ { print $2 }'`

Comment: Unix "cut" is easier... `svn status | grep '\!' | cut -d' ' -f2- > removedProjs`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print rest of the fields in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457486/print-rest-of-the-fields-in-awk)

Comment: @tripleee: I'm so happy that you mentioned this - I'm frustrated at seeing it everywhere!

Answer (score 694, accepted):

Print all columns:

```
awk '{print $0}' somefile
```

Print all but the first column:

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}' somefile
```

Print all but the first two columns:

```
awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' somefile
```

Comment: @zed very nice, just make sure you use `$1` for anything you might need, before changing it.

Comment: gotcha: leaves a leading space dangling about :(

Comment: `cat somefile` can be always replaced with `< somefile` at the end of `awk` command

Comment: @raphinesse you can fix that with `awk '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' input_filename > output_filename`

Comment: This doesn't work with non-whitespace delimiters, replaces them with a space.

Comment: Another thing to note (when used with the default separator): folds spans of multiple embedded spaces into a single space each.
If this is undesired or not even a concern, here's a simpler, more easily generalized solution to get everything from the 3rd field - simply replace `{2}` with the `{}`-enclosed number of preceding fields to eliminate; adapted from @savvadia's answer: `awk '{sub(/^[ ]*([^ ]+ +){2}/, ""); print $0}`

Comment: Great answer. This prints all but last column:
`cat somefile | awk '{$NF=""; print $0}'`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Now, if I want to exclude columns 1-8, is there a way to put a range in there? Rather than `$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""`

Comment: For non-whitespace delimiters, you can specify the Output Field Separator (OFS), e.g. to a comma: `awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$1=""; print $0}'` You will end up with an initial delimiter (`$1` is still included, just as an empty string). You can strip that with `sed` though: `awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$1=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^,//'`

Comment: This answer is not correct. It will only replace the first and second fields with an empty space.

Comment: For multiple lines, and space in names, see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130247/3154883

Comment: @raphinesse - Tried in MobaXterm (a cygwin derivative) so not sure if it will work in all cases, but do `awk '{$1=$2="\b"; print $0}' somefile` will remove the leading white space. Works with `awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4"\b"; print $0}' somefile` as well

Comment: You can also do it with non-whitespace delimiters with `awk -F'-' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS};{$1=$2="\b"; print $0}'`

Comment: AWK is like the overly literal genie who grants three wishes

Comment: @JayRugMan, the `$1=$2="\b"` trick works nicely visually. However, I found that if you do further piping commands (such as `cut`), they may not work properly because the `\b` will be passed on. You can see it with `| tr '\b' '_'`.

Comment: `awk '{$1=""; printf substr($0,1)"\n"}'` worked well for me -- removed the leading space.

Comment: to remove leading space you can also just use gsub : `awk '/>/ {$1=""; gsub(/^ /,""); print}' somefile`

Comment: It is also possible to modify the columns and then print everything. `awk '{$1 = $1 + 1; print}'` ... instead of printing a new column and then thinking how to remove the old one.

Comment: @RyanWardValverde : yeah unlike `perl` that onmi powerful wizard that none are treating as a serious candidate for big data and scientific computing.

Answer (score 123):

There's a duplicate question with a [simpler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3053905/411282) using cut:

```
 svn status |  grep '\!' | cut -d\  -f2-
```

`-d` specifies the delimeter *(space)*, `-f` specifies the list of columns *(all starting with the 2nd)*

Comment: You can also use "-b" to specify the position (from the Nth character onwards).

Comment: As a note, although this performs the same task as the `awk` version, there are line buffering issues with `cut`, which `awk` doesn't have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360640/tail-f-into-grep-into-cut-not-working-properly

Comment: Nice and simple, but comes with a caveat: `awk` treats multiple adjacent space chars. as a *single* separator, while `cut` does not; also - although this is not a problem in the case at hand - `cut` only accepts a single, literal char. as the delimiter, whereas `awk` allows a regex.

Comment: Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217130/8852408, is probable that this solution isn't very efficient.

Comment: @Joaquin I upvoted your comment but then ran some quick, non-scientific benchmarks on a log file of 120MB: (`time cut -d\  -f2- logfile.txt > /dev/null` vs. `time awk '{$1=""; print $0}' logfile.txt > /dev/null`). The `cut` command (without any `grep`) was consistently faster than the `awk` equivalent (average time of `cut` was 70% of the `awk` command). It looks like `cut` is slower at "seeking" though a file to get to a certain line -- but is efficient at processing each line at a time.

Comment: @mklement0 I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476712/1819810) should help. That is, `echo "fo o  ba 
 r" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3-`

Answer (score 120):

You could use a for-loop to loop through printing fields $2 through $NF (built-in variable that represents the number of fields on the line).

Edit:
Since "print" appends a newline, you'll want to buffer the results:

```
awk '{out = ""; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {out = out " " $i}; print out}'
```

Alternatively, use printf:

```
awk '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {printf "%s ", $i}; printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: So I tried this, but think I'm missing something.. here is what I did

svn status | grep '\!' | gawk '{for (i=1; i<=$NF; i++)print $i " ";}' > removedProjs

Comment: Since print appends a newline, you'll want to buffer the results. See my edit.

Comment: When I do that I get a msg that says ^ unterminated string

Comment: heres my exact line:

svn status | grep '\!' | gawk "{out=""; for(i=2; i<= NF; i++){out=$out" "$i;} print $out}" > removedProjs

Comment: It is because you are using " " to enclose your awk script. Use ' ' instead. Also, it may be simpler to just use printf instead of buffering the result.

Comment: K, figured out that the error is because I use double quotes, but I think something with cygwin doesn't like single quotes, cause then it says it is missing the file.

Comment: I like this answer better because it shows how to loop through fields.

Comment: If you want print to use a space, change the output record separator: awk '{ORS=" "; for(i=2;i<NF;i++) print $i}' somefile

Comment: At least on my machine, @ VeeArr .. 
Your syntax is wrong for your first code line. The reply by Wim works. You should not have '$out' (twice). It should just be 'out'.

Comment: Very good solution because it is open for extension where the highest rated answer's is not.

Comment: Have you tested your answer? `awk '{out=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=$out" "$i}; print $out}'` won't work at all. Use `awk '{out=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=out" "$i}; print out}'` instead.

Comment: There will always be some spaces too much. This works better: `'{for(i=11;i<=NF-1;i++){printf "%s ", $i}; print $NF;}'` No leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 29):

```
awk '{out=$2; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){out=out" "$i}; print out}'
```

My answer is based on [the one of VeeArr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last/2961711#2961711), but I noticed it started with a white space before it would print the second column (and the rest). As I only have 1 reputation point, I can't comment on it, so here it goes as a new answer:

start with "out" as the second column and then add all the other columns (if they exist). This goes well as long as there is a second column.

Comment: Excellent, also you removed the $ in front of the out variable which is important too.

Comment: I like this answer better than VeeArr's because if the delimiter is something other than a space (for example - a multi-char string), its easy to get this script to put back the delimiter and in VeeArr's answer, if I try to do that, the delimiter is also added at the end, annoyingly.

Answer (score 19):

Most solutions with awk leave an space. The options here avoid that problem.

#### Option 1

A simple cut solution (works only with single delimiters):

```
command | cut -d' ' -f3-
```

#### Option 2

Forcing an awk re-calc sometimes remove the added leading space (OFS) left by removing the first fields (works with some versions of awk):

```
command | awk '{ $1=$2="";$0=$0;} NF=NF'
```

#### Option 3

Printing each field formatted with `printf` will give more control:

```
$ in='    1    2  3     4   5   6 7     8  '
$ echo "$in"|awk -v n=2 '{ for(i=n+1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?RS:OFS);}'
3 4 5 6 7 8
```

However, all previous answers change all repeated FS  between fields to OFS. Let's build a couple of option that do not do that.

#### Option 4 (recommended)

A loop with sub to remove fields and delimiters at the front.
And using the value of FS instead of space (which could be changed).
Is more portable, and doesn't trigger a change of FS to OFS:
**NOTE:** The `^[FS]*` is to accept an input with leading spaces.

```
$ in='    1    2  3     4   5   6 7     8  '
$ echo "$in" | awk '{ n=2; a="^["FS"]*[^"FS"]+["FS"]+";
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) sub( a , "" , $0 ) } 1 '
3     4   5   6 7     8
```

#### Option 5

It is quite possible to build a solution that does not add extra (leading or trailing) whitespace, and preserve existing whitespace(s) using the function `gensub` from GNU awk, as this:

```
$ echo '    1    2  3     4   5   6 7     8  ' |
  awk -v n=2 'BEGIN{ a="^["FS"]*"; b="([^"FS"]+["FS"]+)"; c="{"n"}"; }
          { print(gensub(a""b""c,"",1)); }'
3     4   5   6 7     8
```

It also may be used to swap a group of fields given a count `n`:

```
$ echo '    1    2  3     4   5   6 7     8  ' |
  awk -v n=2 'BEGIN{ a="^["FS"]*"; b="([^"FS"]+["FS"]+)"; c="{"n"}"; }
          {
            d=gensub(a""b""c,"",1);
            e=gensub("^(.*)"d,"\\1",1,$0);
            print("|"d"|","!"e"!");
          }'
|3     4   5   6 7     8  | !    1    2  !
```

Of course, in such case, the OFS is used to separate both parts of the line, and the trailing white space of the fields is still printed.

**NOTE:** `[FS]*` is used to allow leading spaces in the input line.

Comment: While options 4 and 5 are on the right track, they only work if FS is the default value of `" "` since the regexps are designed to skip leading occurrences of the FS but that would be a bug if the FS was any other single character, e.g. `,`, and you can't negate a multi-char FS in a bracket expression (`e.g. trying to do `"^["FS"]"` when `FS="foo"`) so using FS in the construction of the regexp isn't useful and is misleading.

Answer (score 16):

I personally tried all the answers mentioned above, but most of them were a bit complex or just not right. The easiest way to do it from my point of view is:

```
awk -F" " '{ for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) print $i }'
```

1. Where   -F" "  defines the delimiter for awk to use. In my case is the whitespace, which is also the default delimiter for awk. This means that -F" " can be ignored.
2. Where  NF  defines the total number of fields/columns. Therefore the loop will begin from the 4th field up to the last field/column.
3. Where   $N  retrieves the value of the Nth field. Therefore   print $i   will print the current field/column based based on the loop count.

Comment: Problem, that prints each field on a different line.

Comment: nothing stops you appending this at the end :-) ` | tr '\n' ' ' `

Comment: A bit late but awk '{ for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%s ", $i } }'

Answer (score 11):

```
awk '{ for(i=3; i<=NF; ++i) printf $i""FS; print "" }'
```

[lauhub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011366/lauhub) proposed this correct, simple and fast solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602063/1842877)

Answer (score 9):

This was irritating me so much, I sat down and wrote a `cut`-like field specification parser, tested with GNU Awk 3.1.7.

First, create a new Awk library script called `pfcut`, with e.g.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/awk/pfcut
```

Then, paste in the script below, and save. After that, this is how the usage looks like:

```
$ echo "t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7" | awk -f pfcut --source '/^/ { pfcut("-4"); }'
t1 t2 t3 t4

$ echo "t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7" | awk -f pfcut --source '/^/ { pfcut("2-"); }'
t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7

$ echo "t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7" | awk -f pfcut --source '/^/ { pfcut("-2,4,6-"); }'
t1 t2 t4 t6 t7
```

To avoid typing all that, I guess the best one can do (see otherwise [Automatically load a user function at startup with awk? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102794/automatically-load-a-user-function-at-startup-with-awk)) is add an alias to `~/.bashrc`; e.g. with:

```
$ echo "alias awk-pfcut='awk -f pfcut --source'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc     # refresh bash aliases
```

... then you can just call:

```
$ echo "t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7" | awk-pfcut '/^/ { pfcut("-2,4,6-"); }'
t1 t2 t4 t6 t7
```

Here is the source of the `pfcut` script:

```
# pfcut - print fields like cut
#
# sdaau, GNU GPL
# Nov, 2013

function spfcut(formatstring)
{
  # parse format string
  numsplitscomma = split(formatstring, fsa, ",");
  numspecparts = 0;
  split("", parts); # clear/initialize array (for e.g. `tail` piping into `awk`)
  for(i=1;i<=numsplitscomma;i++) {
    commapart=fsa[i];
    numsplitsminus = split(fsa[i], cpa, "-");
    # assume here a range is always just two parts: "a-b"
    # also assume user has already sorted the ranges
    #print numsplitsminus, cpa[1], cpa[2]; # debug
    if(numsplitsminus==2) {
     if ((cpa[1]) == "") cpa[1] = 1;
     if ((cpa[2]) == "") cpa[2] = NF;
     for(j=cpa[1];j<=cpa[2];j++) {
       parts[numspecparts++] = j;
     }
    } else parts[numspecparts++] = commapart;
  }
  n=asort(parts); outs="";
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    outs = outs sprintf("%s%s", $parts[i], (i==n)?"":OFS); 
    #print(i, parts[i]); # debug
  }
  return outs;
}

function pfcut(formatstring) {
  print spfcut(formatstring);
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use `cut`, not `awk`

Comment: @roblogic : unix cut is fine for small tasks like a few megs. Maybe low hundreds of MBs is probably the crossover point where cut is too slow for the volumes indeed, and where awk truly shines.

Answer (score 7):

Would this work?

```
awk '{print substr($0,length($1)+1);}' < file
```

It leaves some whitespace in front though.

Answer (score 5):

Printing out columns starting from #2 (the output will have no trailing space in the beginning):

```
ls -l | awk '{sub(/[^ ]+ /, ""); print $0}'
```

Comment: Nice, though you should add `+` after the space, since the fields may be separated by more than 1 space (`awk` treats multiple adjacent spaces as a single separator). Also, `awk` will ignore leading spaces, so you should start the regex with `^[ ]*`.
With space as the separator you could even generalize the solution; e.g., the following returns everything from the 3rd field: `awk '{sub(/^[ ]*([^ ]+ +){2}/, ""); print $0}'`
It gets trickier with arbitrary field separators, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5 6" | awk '{ $NF = ""; print $0}'
```

this one uses awk to print all except the last field

Comment: @Birei : you can shorten that to barely just : `awk -- --NF`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I preferred from all the recommendations:

Printing from the 6th to last column.

```
ls -lthr | awk '{out=$6; for(i=7;i<=NF;i++){out=out" "$i}; print out}'
```

or

```
ls -lthr | awk '{ORS=" "; for(i=6;i<=NF;i++) print $i;print "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need specific columns printed with arbitrary delimeter:

```
awk '{print $3 "  " $4}'
```

> col#3  col#4

```
awk '{print $3 "anything" $4}'
```

> col#3anythingcol#4

So if you have whitespace in a column it will be two columns, but you can connect it with any delimiter or without it.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane 'splice @F,0,1; print join " ",@F' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the perl code

`splice @F,0,1` cleanly removes column 0 from the @F array

`join " ",@F` joins the elements of the @F array, using a space in-between each element

---

Python solution:

`python -c "import sys;[sys.stdout.write(' '.join(line.split()[1:]) + '\n') for line in sys.stdin]" < file`

Answer (score 2):

I want to extend the proposed answers to the situation where fields are delimited by possibly *several whitespaces* –the reason why the OP is not using `cut` I suppose.

I know the OP asked about `awk`, but a `sed` approach would work here (example with printing columns from the 5th to the last):

- pure sed approach

  ```
    sed -r 's/^\s*(\S+\s+){4}//' somefile
  ```

  Explanation:

  - `s///` is the standard command to perform substitution
  - `^\s*` matches any consecutive whitespace at the beginning of the line
  - `\S+\s+` means a column of data (non-whitespace chars followed by whitespace chars)
  - `(){4}` means the pattern is repeated 4 times.
- sed and cut

  ```
    sed -r 's/^\s+//; s/\s+/\t/g' somefile | cut -f5-
  ```

  by just replacing consecutive whitespaces by a single tab;
- tr and cut:
  `tr` can also be used to [squeeze consecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483833/4614641) characters with the `-s` option.

  ```
    tr -s [:blank:] <somefile | cut -d' ' -f5-
  ```

Comment: I agree `sed` works best for this problem. Note: The `cut` examples you give won't preserve consecutive spaces in the part that you're trying to extract. Consider this input: `a b c d The     rest`. Your answer would be better if you kept only the pure sed approach. Also use `-E` instead of `-r` for portability. Also, since `\s` is a GNU extension, replace `\s` with `[ \t]` and replace `\S` with `[^ \t]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reformat the part of the line that you don't chop off, the best solution I can think of is written in my answer in:

[How to print all the columns after a particular number using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081916/how-to-print-all-the-columns-after-a-particular-number-using-awk/23118210#23118210)

It  chops what is before the given field number N, and prints all the rest of the line, including field number N and maintaining the original spacing (it does not reformat). It doesn't mater if the string of the field appears also somewhere else in the line.

Define a function:

```
fromField () { 
awk -v m="\x01" -v N="$1" '{$N=m$N; print substr($0,index($0,m)+1)}'
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$ echo "  bat   bi       iru   lau bost   " | fromField 3
iru   lau bost   
$ echo "  bat   bi       iru   lau bost   " | fromField 2
bi       iru   lau bost
```

Output maintains everything, including trailing spaces

In you particular case:

```
svn status | grep '\!' | fromField 2 > removedProjs
```

If your file/stream does not contain new-line characters in the middle of the lines (you could be using a different Record Separator), you can use:

```
awk -v m="\x0a" -v N="3" '{$N=m$N ;print substr($0, index($0,m)+1)}'
```

The first case will fail only in files/streams that contain the rare hexadecimal char number 1

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` function returns substring of `$0` that includes fields from `begin` to `end`:

```
function fields(begin, end,    b, e, p, i) {
    b = 0; e = 0; p = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (begin == i) { b = p; }
        p += length($i);
        e = p;
        if (end == i) { break; }
        p += length(FS);
    }
    return substr($0, b + 1, e - b);
}
```

To get everything starting from field 3:

```
tail = fields(3);
```

To get section of `$0` that covers fields 3 to 5:

```
middle = fields(3, 5);
```

`b, e, p, i` nonsense in function parameter list is just an `awk` way of declaring local variables.

Comment: This is a nice general-purpose function, but it breaks if you have mutliple separators between fields, since awk collapses multiple separators into one, but you're only adding one FS when accounting for the position.

Comment: @cincodenada : the "multiple collapse" part is only active by default when `FS` is the default `" " ( 0x20 \40 )`, which is a special case. the collapsing wld only happen if you made it `"[ ]+"`, plus the fact any custom `FS` turns off pre-trimming of the leading/trailing edges, so an input of  `"  ABC "` (2 spaces 3 `ASCII` letters and 1 more space) against an `FS = "[ ]+"` results in `NF == 3` : only `$2` is populated with `ABC` while `$1` and $3` are empty fields right off the bat.  With `FS = "[ ]"` that input becomes `NF==4` / `$3 == "ABC"`

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers given here and in linked questions fail in various ways given various possible FS values. Some leave leading and/or trailing white space, some convert every FS to the OFS, some rely on semantics that only apply when FS is the default value, some rely on negating FS in a bracket expression which will fail given a multi-char FS, etc.

To do this robustly for any FS, use GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    for ( i=n; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        printf "%s%s", flds[i], seps[i]
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ printf 'a   b c    d\n' | awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk
c    d

$ printf ' a   b c    d\n' | awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk
c    d

$ printf ' a   b c    d\n' | awk -v n=3 -F'[ ]' -f tst.awk
  b c    d

$ printf ' a   b c    d\n' | awk -v n=3 -F'[ ]+' -f tst.awk
b c    d

$ printf 'a###b###c###d\n' | awk -v n=3 -F'###' -f tst.awk
c###d

$ printf '###a###b###c###d\n' | awk -v n=3 -F'###' -f tst.awk
b###c###d
```

Note that I'm using split() above because it's 3rg arg is a **field separator**, not just a regexp like the 2nd arg to match(). The difference is that field separators have additional semantics to regexps such as skipping leading and/or trailing blanks when the separator is a single blank char - if you wanted to use a while(match()) loop or any form of *sub() to emulate the above then you'd need to write code to implement those semantics whereas split() already implements them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
@m=`ls -ltr dir | grep ^d | awk '{print \$6,\$7,\$8,\$9}'`;
foreach $i (@m)
{
        print "$i\n";

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which generalises the requirement to _printing from the Nth column to the end_.

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you are using Bash and you could use as many 'x ' as elements you wish to discard and it ignores multiple spaces if they are not escaped.

```
while read x b; do echo "$b"; done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk examples looks complex here, here is simple Bash shell syntax:

```
command | while read -a cols; do echo ${cols[@]:1}; done
```

Where `1` is your *n*th column counting from 0.

---

#### Example

Given this content of file (`in.txt`):

```
c1
c1 c2
c1 c2 c3
c1 c2 c3 c4
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
```

here is the output:

```
$ while read -a cols; do echo ${cols[@]:1}; done < in.txt 

c2
c2 c3
c2 c3 c4
c2 c3 c4 c5
```

Comment: I also came to conclusion that that's not a good use case for `awk`. Your solution might come in handy in some cases, but it doesn't preserve consecutive spaces. A [pure `sed` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326806/52499) looks optimal to me. Additionally it doesn't need `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

if you wanna use no function calls at all while preserving the spaces and tabs in between the remaining fields, then do :

```
echo  "    1   2  33  4444 555555 \t6666666    " | 

{m,g}awk ++NF FS='^[ \t]*[^ \t]*[ \t]+|[ \t]+$' OFS=
```

=

```
2  33  4444 555555     6666666
```

===================

You can make it a lot more straight forward :

```
 svn status | [m/g]awk   '/!/*sub("^[^ \t]*[ \t]+",_)'

 svn status |   [n]awk '(/!/)*sub("^[^ \t]*[ \t]+",_)'
```

Automatically takes care of the `grep` earlier in the pipe, as well as trimming out extra `FS` after blanking out `$1`, with the added bonus of leaving rest of the original input untouched instead of having tabs overwritten with spaces (unless that's the desired effect)

If you're very certain `$1` does not contain special characters  that need regex escaping, then it's even easier :

```
mawk         '/!/*sub($!_"[ \t]+",_)'
gawk -c/P/e '/!/*sub($!_"""[ \t]+",_)'
```

Or if you prefer customizing `FS+OFS` to handle it all :

```
mawk 'NF*=/!/' FS='^[^ \t]*[ \t]+' OFS='' # this version uses OFS
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a reasonably comprehensive `awk`-field-sub-string-extraction function that

- returns substring of `$0` based on input ranges, **inclusive**
- clamp in out of range values,
- handle ***variable length*** field `SEPs`
- has speedup treatments for ::

> - completely no inputs, returning `$0` directly
> - input values resulting in guaranteed empty string `("")`
> - `FROM-field == 1`
> - `FS = ""` that has split `$0` out by individual chars
>   *(so the `FROM <(_)>` and `TO <(__)>` fields behave like `cut -c` rather than `cut -f`)*

- original `$0` restored, w/o overwriting `FS` seps with `OFS`

|

```
 {m,g}awk '{
 2         print "\n|---BEFORE-------------------------\n"
 3         ($0) "\n|----------------------------\n\n  ["
 4         fld2(2, 5) "]\n  [" fld2(3) "]\n  [" fld2(4, 2)
 5         "]<----------------------------------------------should be
 6         empty\n  [" fld2(3, 11) "]<------------------------should be
 7         capped by NF\n  [" fld2() "]\n  [" fld2((OFS=FS="")*($0=$0)+11,
 8         23) "]<-------------------FS=\"\", split by chars
 9         \n\n|---AFTER-------------------------\n" ($0)
10         "\n|----------------------------"
11  }


12  function fld2(_,__,___,____,_____)
13  {
           if (+__==(_=-_<+_ ?+_:_<_) || (___=____="")==__ || !NF) {
              return $_
16         } else if (NF<_ || (__=NF<+__?NF:+__)<(_=+_?_:!_)) {
              return ___
18         } else if (___==FS || _==!___) {
19            return ___<FS \
                 ? substr("",$!_=$!_ substr("",__=$!(NF=__)))__
20               : substr($(_<_),_,__)
21         }
22         _____=$+(____=___="\37\36\35\32\31\30\27\26\25"\
                              "\24\23\21\20\17\16\6\5\4\3\2\1")
23         NF=__
24         if ($(!_)~("["(___)"]")) {
25            gsub("..","\\&&",___) + gsub(".",___,____)
27            ___=____
28         }
29         __=(_) substr("",_+=_^=_<_)

30         while(___!="") {
31            if ($(!_)!~(____=substr(___,--_,++_))) {
32               ___=____
33            break }
35            ___=substr(___,_+_^(!_))
36         }
37         return \
           substr("",($__=___ $__)==(__=substr($!_,
              _+index($!_,___))),_*($!_=_____))(__)
    }'
```

*those* **`<TAB>`** *are actual* `\t \011` *but relabeled for display clarity*

```
|---BEFORE------------------------- 
       1   2  33  4444 555555 <TAB>6666666    
|----------------------------

  [2 33 4444 555555]
  [33]
  []<---------------------------------------------- should be empty
  [33 4444 555555 6666666]<------------------------ should be capped by NF
  [       1   2  33  4444 555555 <TAB>6666666    ]
  [ 2  33  4444 555555 <TAB>66]<------------------- FS="", split by chars 

|---AFTER------------------------- 
       1   2  33  4444 555555 <TAB>6666666    
|----------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -la | awk '{o=$1" "$3; for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) o=o" "$i; print o }'
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5661537/1041319) is not bad but the natural spacing is gone.
Please then compare it to this one:

```
ls -la | cut -d\  -f4-
```

Then you'd see the difference.

Even `ls -la | awk '{$1=$2=""; print}'` which is based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961994/1041319) voted best thus far is not preserve the formatting.

Thus I would use the following, and it also allows explicit selective columns in the beginning:

```
ls -la | cut -d\  -f1,4-
```

Note that every space counts for columns too, so for instance in the below, columns 1 and 3 are empty, 2 is INFO and 4 is:

```
$ echo " INFO  2014-10-11 10:16:19  main " | cut -d\  -f1,3

$ echo " INFO  2014-10-11 10:16:19  main " | cut -d\  -f2,4
INFO 2014-10-11
$
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want formatted text, chain your commands with echo and use $0 to print the last field.

Example:

```
for i in {8..11}; do
   s1="$i"
   s2="str$i"
   s3="str with spaces $i"
   echo -n "$s1 $s2" | awk '{printf "|%3d|%6s",$1,$2}'
   echo -en "$s3" | awk '{printf "|%-19s|\n", $0}'
done
```

Prints:

```
|  8|  str8|str with spaces 8  |
|  9|  str9|str with spaces 9  |
| 10| str10|str with spaces 10 |
| 11| str11|str with spaces 11 |
```

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't happy with any of the `awk` solutions presented here because I wanted to extract the first few columns and then print the rest, so I turned to `perl` instead. The following code extracts the first two columns, and displays the rest as is:

```
echo -e "a  b  c  d\te\t\tf g" | \
  perl -ne 'my @f = split /\s+/, $_, 3; printf "first: %s second: %s rest: %s", @f;'
```

The advantage compared to the `perl` solution from [Chris Koknat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32597673/1100614) is that really only the first n elements are split off from the input string; the rest of the string isn't split at all and therefor stays completely intact. My example demonstrates this with a mix of spaces and tabs.

To change the amount of columns that should be extracted, replace the `3` in the example with n+1.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> __='    1    2  3     4   5   6 7     8  '
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> printf '%s' "$__" | od
> ```

```
0000000         538976288       538976305       538980896       538976307
                           1                   2           3            
          040 040 040 040 061 040 040 040 040 062 040 040 063 040 040 040
          sp  sp  sp  sp   1  sp  sp  sp  sp   2  sp  sp   3  sp  sp  sp
           32  32  32  32  49  32  32  32  32  50  32  32  51  32  32  32
           20  20  20  20  31  20  20  20  20  32  20  20  33  20  20  20

0000020         540287008       540352544       540418080       538976311
                   4               5               6       7            
          040 040 064 040 040 040 065 040 040 040 066 040 067 040 040 040
          sp  sp   4  sp  sp  sp   5  sp  sp  sp   6  sp   7  sp  sp  sp
           32  32  52  32  32  32  53  32  32  32  54  32  55  32  32  32
           20  20  34  20  20  20  35  20  20  20  36  20  37  20  20  20

0000040         540549152              32                                
                   8                                                    
          040 040 070 040 040                                            
          sp  sp   8  sp  sp                                            
           32  32  56  32  32                                            
           20  20  38  20  20
```

> ```
> printf '\42%s\42' "$__"
> ```

`"    1    2  3     4   5   6 7     8  "`

> ---
>
> ```
> mawk ++NF FS='^[ \t]*[^ \t]+[ \t]+' OFS='"'
> ```

`"2  3     4   5   6 7     8  "`

This approach preserves all multi-blank seps between fields by specifically targeting just the head.

Answer (score -11):

The top-voted [answer by zed_0xff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961994) did not work for me.

I have a log where after $5 with an IP address can be more text or no text. I need everything from the IP address to the end of the line should there be anything after $5. In my case, this is actually within an awk program, not an awk one-liner so awk must solve the problem. When I try to remove the first 4 fields using the solution proposed by zed_0xff:

```
echo "  7 27.10.16. Thu 11:57:18 37.244.182.218" | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=""; printf "[%s]\n", $0}'
```

it spits out wrong and useless response (I added [..] to demonstrate):

```
[    37.244.182.218 one two three]
```

There are even some suggestions to combine substr with this wrong answer, but that only complicates things. It offers no improvement.

Instead, if columns are fixed width until the cut point and awk is needed, the correct answer is:

```
echo "  7 27.10.16. Thu 11:57:18 37.244.182.218" | awk '{printf "[%s]\n", substr($0,28)}'
```

which produces the desired output:

```
[37.244.182.218 one two three]
```