# awk + Need to print everything (all rest fields) except $1 and $2

Tags: awk, filtering

I have the following file and I need to print everything except `$1` and `$2` by `awk`

File:

```
INFORMATION DATA 12 33 55 33 66 43 
INFORMATION DATA 45 76 44 66 77 33 
INFORMATION DATA 77 83 56 77 88 22
...
```

the desirable output:

```
 12 33 55 33 66 43 
 45 76 44 66 77 33 
 77 83 56 77 88 22
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last)

Answer (score 23):

Well, given your data, cut should be sufficient:

```
cut -d\  -f3- infile
```

Answer (score 12):

Although it adds an extra space at the beginning of each line compared to yael's expected output, here is a shorter and simpler awk based solution than the previously suggested ones:

```
awk '{$1=$2=""; print}'
```

or even:

```
awk '{$1=$2=""}1'
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the leading spaces you can do `awk '{$1=$2="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1' file`

Answer (score 11):

```
$ cat t
INFORMATION DATA 12 33 55 33 66 43
INFORMATION DATA 45 76 44 66 77 33
INFORMATION DATA 77 83 56 77 88 22

$ awk '{for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) printf $i " "; print ""}' t 
12 33 55 33 66 43 
45 76 44 66 77 33 
77 83 56 77 88 22
```

Comment: Even if for the current question there is simpler than awk (see below), if you have to do some calculation on your data then it is very useful to know your loop! One colleague of mine had to perform additions on the two first columns and then print the other ones as is: a simple printf block followed by your block did the trick. Thanks for the answer (which I plused :-) ).

Answer (score 3):

danbens answer leaves a whitespace at the end of the resulting string. so the correct way to do it would be:

```
awk '{for (i=3; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}' filename
```

Comment: awk '{for (i=3; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $i}' filename yields the same result. Would you know why?

Answer (score 2):

If the first two words don't change, probably the simplest thing would be:

```
awk -F 'INFORMATION DATA ' '{print $2}' t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `awk` solution, that's more flexible than the `cut` one and is shorter than the other `awk` ones. Assuming your separators are single spaces (modify the regex as necessary if they are not):

```
awk --posix '{sub(/([^ ]* ){2}/, ""); print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -lane 'splice @F,0,2; print join " ",@F' file
```

These command-line options are used:
`-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print it
`-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
`-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array. Defaults to splitting on whitespace
`-e` execute the perl code

`splice @F,0,2` cleanly removes columns 0 and 1 from the `@F` array
`join " ",@F` joins the elements of the `@F` array, using a space in-between each element

Variation for csv input files:

```
perl -F, -lane 'splice @F,0,2; print join " ",@F' file
```

This uses the `-F` field separator option with a comma