# How to use a regex for the field separator in AWK?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk

I read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544989/2909897) that show how one can set the field separator using the `-F` flag:

```
awk -F 'INFORMATION DATA ' '{print $2}' t
```

Now I'm curious how I can use a regex for the field separator. My attempt can be seen below:

```
$ echo "1 2 foo\n2 3 bar\n42 2 baz"
1 2 foo
2 3 bar
42 2 baz
$ echo "1 2 foo\n2 3 bar\n42 2 baz" | awk -F '\d+ \d+ ' '{ print $2 }'
# 3 blank lines
```

I was expecting to get the following output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

This is because my regex `\d+ \d+` matches "the first 2 numbers separated by a space, followed by a space". But I'm printing the second record. As shown on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/jpSVUvCGHr):

[image]

- How do I use a regex as the awk field separator?

Comment: I'm awk I'm printing $2, the second record

Comment: awk dow not support the perlish `\d` metacharacter. You would use the POSIX character class of `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `echo` doesn't auto escape and outputs a literal `\n`. So you'll need to add `-e` to enable escapes. Second of all `awk` doesn't support `\d` so you have to use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

```
echo -e "1 2 foo\n2 3 bar\n42 2 baz" | awk -F '[0-9]+ [0-9]+ ' '{ print $2 }'
```

or

```
echo -e "1 2 foo\n2 3 bar\n42 2 baz" | awk -F '[[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ ' '{ print $2 }'
```

Both outputs:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: 4 seconds difference!

Comment: Damn! Even ended up looking quite the same! :)

Comment: FYI some versions of echo DO print a literal newline given `\n`. That's one of the reasons it's best to avoid using echo - it's behavior is non-portable. Use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `\d` with `[0-9]`:

With this you can print all the fields and you can see the fields immediatelly:

```
$ echo -e "1 2 foo\n2 3 bar\n42 2 baz" |awk -v FS="[0-9]+ [0-9]+" '{for (k=1;k<=NF;k++) print k,$k}'
1 
2  foo
1 
2  bar
1 
2  baz
```

So just use [0-9] in your command:

```
$ echo -e "1 2 foo\n2 3 bar\n42 2 baz" |awk -v FS="[0-9]+ [0-9]+" '{print $2}'
 foo
 bar
 baz
```