# How to make the 'cut' command treat same sequental delimiters as one?

Tags: bash, unix, delimiter, cut

I'm trying to extract a certain (the fourth) field from the column-based, 'space'-adjusted text stream. I'm trying to use the `cut` command in the following manner:

`cat text.txt | cut -d " " -f 4`

Unfortunately, `cut` doesn't treat several spaces as one delimiter. I could have piped through awk

`awk '{ printf $4; }'`

or sed

`sed  -E "s/[[:space:]]+/ /g"`

to collapse the spaces, but I'd like to know if there any way to deal with `cut` and several delimiters natively?

Comment: AWK is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux cut help - how to specify more spaces for the delimiter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142735/linux-cut-help-how-to-specify-more-spaces-for-the-delimiter)

Comment: I love `awk` BUT when you are doing `kubectl ... bash -c 'awk ...'` and similar, things start to get funny with quotes, parameter references, etc. Then it's actually quite nice to whip out the old rudimentary tools from the toolbox.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76824903/22330192) below, for a very convenient way to achive the desired results, and please help with getting my patch upstreamed to everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 592, accepted):

Try:

```
tr -s ' ' <text.txt | cut -d ' ' -f4
```

From the `tr` man page:

```
-s, --squeeze-repeats   replace each input sequence of a repeated character
                        that is listed in SET1 with a single occurrence
                        of that character
```

Comment: No need for `cat` here.  You could pass `< text.txt` directly to `tr`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: Not sure it is any simpler, but you are going to merge, you can forgo cut's `-d` and translate straight from multiple characters to tab. For example: I came here looking for a way to automatically export my display: `who am i | tr -s ' ()' '\t' | cut -f5`

Comment: This doesn't remove leading/trailing whitespace (which may or may not be wanted, but usually isn't), in contrast with the awk solution. The awk solution is also much more readable and less verbose.

Comment: -1 **WARNING: THIS IS NOT THE SAME THING AS TREATING SEQUENTIAL DELIMETERS AS ONE.** Compare `echo "a b  c" | cut -d " " -f2-`, `echo "a b  c" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2-`

Comment: @user541686 Yes it is. Your example demonstrates exactly this. To see, try changing `-f2-` to `-f3-`. This shows that in the cut-only approach, there are 4 fields: 'a', 'b', '', and 'c', whereas in the tr-cut approach there are only 3: 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

Answer (score 105):

As you comment in your question, `awk` is really the way to go. To use `cut` is possible together with `tr -s` to squeeze spaces, as [kev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483833/1983854) shows.

Let me however go through all the possible combinations for future readers. Explanations are at the Test section.

### tr | cut

```
tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d' ' -f4
```

### awk

```
awk '{print $4}' file
```

### bash

```
while read -r _ _ _ myfield _
do
   echo "forth field: $myfield"
done < file
```

### sed

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]*[ ]*){3}([^ ]*).*/\2/' file
```

---

## Tests

Given this file, let's test the commands:

```
$ cat a
this   is    line     1 more text
this      is line    2     more text
this    is line 3     more text
this is   line 4            more    text
```

### tr | cut

```
$ cut -d' ' -f4 a
is
                        # it does not show what we want!


$ tr -s ' ' < a | cut -d' ' -f4
1
2                       # this makes it!
3
4
$
```

### awk

```
$ awk '{print $4}' a
1
2
3
4
```

### bash

This reads the fields sequentially. By using `_` we indicate that this is a throwaway variable as a "junk variable" to ignore these fields. This way, we store `$myfield` as the 4th field in the file, no matter the spaces in between them.

```
$ while read -r _ _ _ a _; do echo "4th field: $a"; done < a
4th field: 1
4th field: 2
4th field: 3
4th field: 4
```

### sed

This catches three groups of spaces and no spaces with `([^ ]*[ ]*){3}`. Then, it catches whatever coming until a space as the 4th field, that it is finally printed with `\1`.

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^ ]*[ ]*){3}([^ ]*).*/\2/' a
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: `awk` is not only elegant and simple, it is also included in VMware ESXi, where `tr` is missing.

Comment: @user121391 yet another reason to use `awk`!

Comment: @fedorqui I've never heard of the underscore as "junk variable". Can you provide any more insight/reference on this?

Comment: @BryKKan I learnt about it in Greg's [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001): _Some people use the throwaway variable _ as a "junk variable" to ignore fields. It (or indeed any variable) can also be used more than once in a single `read` command, if we don't care what goes into it_. It can be anything, it is just that it somehow became standard instead of `junk_var` or `whatever` :)

Comment: @BryKKan In Javascript it also represents a function parameter that is not meant to be used.

Answer (score 27):

### shortest/friendliest solution

After becoming frustrated with the too many limitations of `cut`, I wrote my own replacement, which I called [**`cuts`**](http://arielf.github.io/cuts/) for "cut on steroids".

[**cuts**](http://arielf.github.io/cuts/) provides what is likely the most minimalist solution to this and *many other* related cut/paste problems.

One example, out of many, addressing this particular question:

```
$ cat text.txt
0   1        2 3
0 1          2   3 4

$ cuts 2 text.txt
2
2
```

[**`cuts`**](http://arielf.github.io/cuts/) supports:

- auto-detection of most common field-delimiters in files (+ ability to override defaults)
- multi-char, mixed-char, and regex matched delimiters
- extracting columns from multiple files with mixed delimiters
- offsets from end of line (using negative numbers) in addition to start of line
- automatic side-by-side pasting of columns (no need to invoke `paste` separately)
- support for field reordering
- a config file where users can change their personal preferences
- great emphasis on user friendliness & minimalist required typing

and much more.  None of which is provided by standard `cut`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24543231/1296044

Source and documentation (free software): [***http://arielf.github.io/cuts/***](http://arielf.github.io/cuts/)

Answer (score 4):

This Perl one-liner shows how closely Perl is related to awk:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[3]' text.txt
```

However, the `@F` autosplit array starts at index `$F[0]` while awk fields start with `$1`

Answer (score 3):

With versions of `cut` I know of, no, this is not possible. `cut` is primarily useful for parsing files where the separator is not whitespace (for example `/etc/passwd`) and that have a fixed number of fields. Two separators in a row mean an empty field, and that goes for whitespace too.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut(1)`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way, by treating several spaces as one delimiter right within `cut(1)`.

In particular, with my patch applied, the following command will perform the desired operation.  It's as simple as that, just add `-m` into the command line:

```
cat text.txt | cut -d ' ' -m -f 4
```

I also submitted this patch upstream, and let's hope that it will eventually be accepted and merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut(1)`, and having some feedback on all that from different people would be great, preferably on the coreutils [mailing list](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/#mailinglists).  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut(1)` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.