# Unix - Need to cut a file which has multiple blanks as delimiter - awk or cut?

Tags: unix, awk, delimiter, cut

I need to get the records from a text file in Unix. The delimiter is multiple blanks. For example:

```
2U2133   1239  
1290fsdsf   3234
```

From this, I need to extract

```
1239  
3234
```

The delimiter for all records will be always 3 blanks.

I need to do this in an unix script(.scr) and write the output to another file or use it as an input to a do-while loop. I tried the below:

```
while read readline  
do  
        read_int=`echo "$readline"`  
        cnt_exc=`grep "$read_int" ${Directory path}/file1.txt| wc -l`  
if [ $cnt_exc -gt 0 ]  
then  
  int_1=0  
else  
  int_2=0  
fi  
done < awk -F'  ' '{ print $2 }' ${Directoty path}/test_file.txt
```

test_file.txt is the input file and file1.txt is a lookup file. But the above way is not working and giving me syntax errors near awk -F

I tried writing the output to a file. The following worked in command line:

```
more test_file.txt | awk -F'   ' '{ print $2 }' > output.txt
```

This is working and writing the records to output.txt in command line. But the same command does not work in the unix script (It is a .scr file)

Please let me know where I am going wrong and how I can resolve this.

Thanks,
Visakh

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142735/linux-cut-help-how-to-specify-more-spaces-for-the-delimiter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the version or implementation of `cut` on your machine.  Some versions support an option, usually `-i`, that means 'ignore blank fields' or, equivalently, allow multiple separators between fields.  If that's supported, use:

```
cut -i -d' ' -f 2 data.file
```

If not (and it is not universal — and maybe not even widespread, since neither GNU nor MacOS X have the option), then using `awk` is better and more portable.

You need to pipe the output of `awk` into your loop, though:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $2}' ${Directory_path}/test_file.txt |
while read readline  
do  
    read_int=`echo "$readline"`  
    cnt_exc=`grep "$read_int" ${Directory_path}/file1.txt| wc -l`  
    if [ $cnt_exc -gt 0 ]  
    then int_1=0  
    else int_2=0
    fi  
done
```

The only residual issue is whether the `while` loop is in a sub-shell and and therefore not modifying your main shell scripts variables, just its own copy of those variables.

With bash, you can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
while read readline  
do  
    read_int=`echo "$readline"`  
    cnt_exc=`grep "$read_int" ${Directory_path}/file1.txt| wc -l`  
    if [ $cnt_exc -gt 0 ]  
    then int_1=0  
    else int_2=0
    fi  
done < <(awk -F' ' '{print $2}' ${Directory_path}/test_file.txt)
```

This leaves the `while` loop in the current shell, but arranges for the output of the command to appear as if from a file.

The blank in `${Directory path}` is not normally legal — unless it is another Bash feature I've missed out on; you also had a typo (`Directoty`) in one place.

Answer (score 30):

**The job of replacing multiple delimiters with just one is left to `tr`:**

```
cat <file_name> | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

`tr` translates or deletes characters, and is perfectly suited to prepare your data for `cut` to work properly.

The [manual](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html) states:

> ```
> -s, --squeeze-repeats
>           replace each sequence  of  a  repeated  character  that  is
>           listed  in the last specified SET, with a single occurrence
>           of that character
> ```

Comment: I like your answer the most, just because using 'tr' and 'cut' is much more elegnat than 'awk' loop. Thanks!

Comment: From `man tr`:

       `-s`, `--squeeze-repeats` - 
              replace each input sequence of  a  repeated  character  that  is
              listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that character

Answer (score 3):

Other ways of doing the same thing aside, the error in your program is this: You cannot redirect from (`<`) the output of another program. Turn your script around and use a pipe like this:

```
awk -F'   ' '{ print $2 }' ${Directory path}/test_file.txt | while read readline
```

etc.

Besides, the use of "readline" as a variable name may or may not get you into problems.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can use the following line

```
sed 's/   /\t/g' <file_name> | cut -f 2
```

to get your second columns.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can start from something like this:

```
for n in `${Directoty path}/test_file.txt | cut -d " " -f 4`
{
    grep -c $n ${Directory path}/file*.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should have been a comment, but since I cannot comment yet, I am adding this here.
This is from an excellent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483833/3138875

```
tr -s ' ' <text.txt | cut -d ' ' -f4
```

`tr -s '<character>'` squeezes multiple repeated instances of `<character>` into one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working in the script because of the typo in "Directo***t***y path" (last line of your script).

Comment: That's part of the trouble; the blank in the name doesn't help either.  The rest is that you have to use more notation to get the output of a shell command supplied as input via I/O redirection rather than piping.

Answer (score 0):

Cut isn't flexible enough. I usually use Perl for that:

```
cat file.txt | perl -F'   ' -e 'print $F[1]."\n"'
```

Instead of a triple space after *-F* you can put any Perl regular expression. You access fields as *$F[n]*, where *n* is the field number (counting starts at zero). This way there is no need to *sed* or *tr*.