# How to specify more spaces for the delimiter using cut?

Tags: linux, delimiter, cut

Is there a way to specify multiple spaces as a field delimiter with the `cut` command (something like a `" "+` regex)?  For example, what field delimiter I should specify for the following string to reach value `3744`?

```
$ps axu | grep jboss

jboss     2574  0.0  0.0   3744  1092 ?        S    Aug17   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/java/jboss/bin/run.sh -c example.com -b 0.0.0.0
```

`cut -d' '` is not what I want, because it's only for a single space. `awk` is not what I am looking for either, so how to do this with `cut`?

Comment: best answer is using `tr` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483833/168143

Comment: Not directly relevant to the actual question being asked but instead of `ps`+`grep` you could use `pgrep` which is available in most modern distros. It will return the result exactly in the form you need it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the 'cut' command treat multiple characters as one delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-multiple-characters-as-one-delimiter)

Comment: These days I just use `hck` as a drop in `cut` replacement. By default it splits on all whitespace, like awk.  And the key feature is that you can specify a delimiter with `-d` like cut, but unlike cut that delimiter can be a regex!  No more needing to pre-process with `tr -s` before passing to cut. You can find `hck` here: https://github.com/sstadick/hck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does CUT support multiple spaces as the delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322968/does-cut-support-multiple-spaces-as-the-delimiter)

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77074659/22330192) below, for a very convenient way to achive the desired results, and please help with getting my patch upstreamed to everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Actually `awk` is *exactly* the tool you should be looking into:

```
ps axu | grep '[j]boss' | awk '{print $5}'
```

or you can ditch the `grep` altogether since `awk` knows about regular expressions:

```
ps axu | awk '/[j]boss/ {print $5}'
```

But if, for some bizarre reason, you really *can't* use `awk`, there are other simpler things you can do, like collapse all whitespace to a single space first:

```
ps axu | grep '[j]boss' | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f5
```

---

That `grep` trick, by the way, is a neat way to only get the `jboss` processes and not the `grep jboss` one (ditto for the `awk` variant as well).

The `grep` process will have a literal `grep [j]boss` in its process command so will not be caught by the `grep` itself, which is looking for the character class `[j]` followed by `boss`.

This is a nifty way to avoid the `| grep xyz | grep -v grep` paradigm that some people use.

Comment: Great answer. I'll be coming back to look this up again next time I need it.

Comment: The `grep` trick seems to not work in crontab files. Any reason?

Comment: I keep learning and forgetting the grep trick.  Thanks for my most recent reminder. Maybe this time it'll stick.  But I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @Michael, you should set up a cron job somewhere to mail that tip (and possibly others) to you once a month :-)

Comment: For that last sed command, you should be able to do `\s+` for "one or more spaces", in place of `\s\s*` which says "space followed by zero or more spaces"

Comment: This is great answer but the OP asked how to do it with cut, so I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/29685565/869951 deserves more credit than it currently has.

Comment: Oliver, sometimes the best answer to "how do I do X with Y?" is "Don't use Y, use Z instead".  Since OP accepted this answer, it's likely I convinced them of that :-)

Answer (score 135):

`awk` version is probably the best way to go, but you can also use `cut` if you firstly squeeze the repeats with `tr`:

```sh
ps axu | grep jbos[s] | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#              |            |             |
#              |            |       get 5th field
#              |            |
#              |        squeeze spaces
#              |
#        avoid grep itself to appear in the list
```

Comment: Fancy illustration.

Comment: `tr -s ' '` is mighty nice! I hope I can remember that better than `awk`

Comment: @Chris I have to object :D Awk is way better for these things!!

Comment: @fedorqui When it comes to print nth field to the end, the [`cut -f5-` grammar, "-fN-"](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucut.htm#Specifying-LIST) is much simpler than [`awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602035/how-to-print-third-column-to-last-column).

Comment: @Weekend agreed.

Answer (score 46):

I like to use the tr -s command for this

```
 ps aux | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d' ' -f3
```

This squeezes all white spaces down to 1 space.  This way telling cut to use a space as a delimiter is honored as expected.

Comment: I think this should be the answer, it is closer to the OP request (asked to use cut). This approach is 5-10% slower than the awk approach (because there is one more pipe to handle with tr), but in general this will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 12):

I am going to nominate `tr -s [:blank:]` as the best answer.

Why do we want to use cut? It has the magic command that says "we want the third field and every field after it, omitting the first two fields"

```
cat log | tr -s [:blank:] |cut -d' ' -f 3-
```

I do not believe there is an equivalent command for awk or perl split where we do not know how many fields there will be, ie out put the 3rd field through field X.

Answer (score 9):

#### Shorter/simpler solution: use [`cuts`](http://arielf.github.io/cuts/) (cut on steroids I wrote)

```
ps axu | grep '[j]boss' | cuts 4
```

*Note that `cuts` field indexes are zero-based so 5th field is specified as 4*

http://arielf.github.io/cuts/

And even shorter (not using cut at all) is:

```
pgrep jboss
```

Answer (score 8):

One way around this is to go:

```
$ps axu | grep jboss | sed 's/\s\+/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

to replace multiple consecutive spaces with a single one.

Comment: Strange, this does not work on OS X. The sed command does not change multiple spaces to one space.

Comment: `\s` is a GNU sed extension. On OS X you can pass the `-E` flag to sed to enable extended regular expressions, then use `[[:space:]]` in place of `\s`, like so: `sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/ /g'`

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I tend to use awk for jobs like this.  For example:

```
ps axu| grep jboss | grep -v grep | awk '{print $5}'
```

Comment: That can be compressed down to `ps axu | awk '/[j]boss/ {print $5}'`.

Comment: Isn't awk slower (especially when there are some superfluous other processes), then sed / grep / cut?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, there is always perl:

```
ps aux | perl -lane 'print $F[3]'
```

Or, if you want to get all fields starting at field #3 (as stated in one of the answers above):

```
ps aux | perl -lane 'print @F[3 .. scalar @F]'
```

Comment: This does not work with the output of `lsof` I tried `lsof|perl -lane 'print $F[5]'` this sometimes gets the 5th column, sometimes the 6th

Comment: I think the question just was how to use delimiters that might contain a varying number of spaces. For this purpose the answer was correct.

Comment: In lsof the problem is that the number of columns is not always consistent in each row.

Comment: You can use this answer: [Get a certain column of an output with content aligned right and some columns not always filled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491770/20661)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pick columns from a ps output, any reason to not use -o?

e.g.

```
ps ax -o pid,vsz
ps ax -o pid,cmd
```

Minimum column width allocated, no padding, only single space field separator.

```
ps ax --no-headers -o pid:1,vsz:1,cmd

3443 24600 -bash
8419 0 [xfsalloc]
8420 0 [xfs_mru_cache]
8602 489316 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
12821 497240 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
12824 497132 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Pid and vsz given 10 char width, 1 space field separator.

```
ps ax --no-headers -o pid:10,vsz:10,cmd

  3443      24600 -bash
  8419          0 [xfsalloc]
  8420          0 [xfs_mru_cache]
  8602     489316 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 12821     497240 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 12824     497132 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Used in a script:-

```
oldpid=12824
echo "PID: ${oldpid}"
echo "Command: $(ps -ho cmd ${oldpid})"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut(1)`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way, by treating several spaces as one delimiter right within `cut(1)`.

In particular, with my patch applied, the following command will perform the desired operation.  It's as simple as that, just add `-m` into the invocation of `cut(1)` and simply use `-d ' ' -f 5` to extract the PID values from the process list produced by `ps(1)`:

```
ps axu | grep jboss | cut -d ' ' -m -f 5
```

I also submitted this patch upstream, and let's hope that it will eventually be accepted and merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut(1)`, and having some feedback on all that from different people would be great, preferably on the coreutils [mailing list](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/#mailinglists).  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut(1)` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.

Comment: My previous answer to this question was deleted because it wasn't tailored specifically to this question.  Thus, I answered this question again, providing a much more specific answer.  I hope it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you must use cut command

```
ps axu | grep [j]boss |awk '$1=$1'|cut -d' ' -f5
```

In Solaris, replace awk with `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

Answer (score 0):

I still like the way Perl handles fields with white space.
First field is $F[0].

```
$ ps axu | grep dbus | perl -lane 'print $F[4]'
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to store the PID to a file in /tmp, and to find the right process using  the `-S` option for `ssh`. That might be a misuse but works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_REDIS=${1:-redis.someserver.com}
PROXY="proxy.somewhere.com"

LOCAL_PORT=${2:-6379}

if [ "$1" == "stop" ] ; then
    kill `cat /tmp/sshTunel${LOCAL_PORT}-pid`
    exit
fi

set -x

ssh -f -i ~/.ssh/aws.pem centos@$PROXY -L $LOCAL_PORT:$TARGET_REDIS:6379 -N -S /tmp/sshTunel$LOCAL_PORT  ## AWS DocService dev, DNS alias
# SSH_PID=$! ## Only works with &
SSH_PID=`ps aux | grep sshTunel${LOCAL_PORT} | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $SSH_PID > /tmp/sshTunel${LOCAL_PORT}-pid
```

Better approach might be to query for the `SSH_PID` right before killing it, since the file might be stale and it would kill a wrong process.