# Does CUT support multiple spaces as the delimiter?

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I have text like this:

```
word1 word2   word3  word4
```

There may be more than one space between a pair of words and I want to get some columns of words from each line . When I use `cat file | cut -d ' ' -f1,2,4` it seems that some fields are space which is not what I expected. I know `awk` can achieve this. The question is can we do this with `cut` only? i.e., can we set multiple spaces as the delimiter in `cut`, yet the number varies?

Comment: since space is the delimiter, the values cannot have spaces. Those values are actually empty strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot. If you want to be able to use more than one character (or even a regex) for the delimiter then use awk instead.

Comment: adding an example with awk would have been great

Answer (score 20):

As others have stated, `cut` can't do it alone (and `awk` is the best choice, because it's the only tool required). If you still want to use `cut`, you can combine it with `tr`, however:

```
tr -s ' ' <<<"word1 word2   word3  word4" | cut -d ' ' -f1,2,4
```

`tr -s ' '` folds each span of multiple spaces into one space each.

Comment: I prefer this to `awk`. Typing all those curlies and having to type out `print` and dollar signs. As long as you remember the `-s` option for "squash", just pipe it through `tr`. It's even one character less than `awk`. What's not to like?

Answer (score 12):

use `awk`, bro: `awk '{print $1, $2, $4;}' file`

Thank you @fedorqui for the sugesstion

Comment: `awk '{print $1, $2, $4;}' file` suffices, no need to `cat`.

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can use the positional parameters

```
line="word1 word2   word3  word4"
set -- $line                       # no quotes here!
echo $1 $2 $4
```

```
word1 word2 word4
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a reasonable IFS (e.g. `IFS=$' \n\t'` ) Use word-splitting before passing to `cut`

```
$ var="word1 word2   word3  word4"; echo $var
word1 word2 word3 word4
$ var="word1 word2   word3  word4"; echo $var | cut -d ' ' -f1,2,4
word1 word2 word4
```

So for you

```
$ var=$(cat "file"); echo $var | cut -d ' ' -f1,2,4
```

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm sorry, delimiter in *cut* is always only one character. But you can use *read* instead

```
while read col1 col2 col3 col4
do
    echo "$col1 $col2 $col4"
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Since BASH's default Internal Field Separator is whitespace, you can avoid using `cut` or any other external tools by using the BASH `read` builtin command.

```
while read f1 f2 _ f4; do echo "$f1 $f2 $f4"; done < file
```

Here, the `_` simply acts as a junk variable for the third field.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut(1)`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way, by allowing multiple spaces as the delimiter right within `cut(1)`.

In particular, with my patch applied, the following command will perform the desired operation.  It's as simple as that, just add `-m` into the command line:

```
cat file | cut -d ' ' -m -f 1,2,4
```

I also submitted this patch upstream, and let's hope that it will eventually be accepted and merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut(1)`, and having some feedback on all that from different people would be great, preferably on the coreutils [mailing list](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/#mailinglists).  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut(1)` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.