# Can't cut column in Linux

Tags: cut

I have a file like this

```
ATOM   3197 HD13 ILE   206       9.900  15.310  13.450  0.0196 1.4870
ATOM   3198  C   ILE   206      10.870  16.560  17.500  0.8343 1.9080
ATOM   3199  OXT ILE   206      11.780  15.734  17.425 -0.8190 1.6612
ATOM   3200  O   ILE   206       9.929  16.225  18.095 -0.8190 1.6612
```

I want to cut the second column, however when I use

```
cut -f1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 filename
```

it doesn't work. Am I do something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux cut help - how to specify more spaces for the delimiter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142735/linux-cut-help-how-to-specify-more-spaces-for-the-delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are multiple spaces and `cut` can just handle them one by one.

You can start from the 5th position:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f 1,5- file
ATOM HD13 ILE   206       9.900  15.310  13.450  0.0196 1.4870
ATOM  C   ILE   206      10.870  16.560  17.500  0.8343 1.9080
ATOM  OXT ILE   206      11.780  15.734  17.425 -0.8190 1.6612
ATOM  O   ILE   206       9.929  16.225  18.095 -0.8190 1.6612
```

Or squeeze spaces with `tr -s` like below (multiple spaces will be lost, though):

```
$ tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
ATOM HD13 ILE 206 9.900 15.310 13.450 0.0196 1.4870
ATOM C ILE 206 10.870 16.560 17.500 0.8343 1.9080
ATOM OXT ILE 206 11.780 15.734 17.425 -0.8190 1.6612
ATOM O ILE 206 9.929 16.225 18.095 -0.8190 1.6612
```

Note you can indicate from `3` to the end with `3-`:

```
tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d' ' -f1,3-
```

---

In fact I would use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{$2=""; print}' file
```

or just

```
awk '{$2=""} 1' file
```

Comment: Wow, it does work. However is there any way to keep the format of others column for keeping it clearly?

Comment: Yes, sure, see the option with `cut -d' ' -f 1,5- file` or `awk` way.

Comment: I have a question. Why does it not similar to 'cut -f1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 filename'?

Comment: Because there are multiple spaces between the columns, so that the 2nd will be empty, the 3rd another one, etc. You can see it by printing one column at a time: `cut -f3 file`, `cut -f4 file`, etc.

Comment: actually it doesn't cut the first 999 lines. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Are you using windows files? Sometimes they screw files. Check with `cat -vte file`.

Comment: no, they are pure Linux files. Is it because starting from 1000, there are four characters?

Comment: Aaaah yes, must be this, @Ooker . Then it is best to use the `awk` approach, not to be format-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

There are many spaces in your file. So, you've to start with number of spaces.

The new.txt contains

```
ATOM   3197 HD13 ILE   206       9.900  15.310  13.450  0.0196 1.4870
ATOM   3198  C   ILE   206      10.870  16.560  17.500  0.8343 1.9080
ATOM   3199  OXT ILE   206      11.780  15.734  17.425 -0.8190 1.6612
ATOM   3200  O   ILE   206       9.929  16.225  18.095 -0.8190 1.6612
```

and this is the command to print second column

```
root@52:/home/ubuntu# cut -d' ' -f4 new.txt

3197
3198
3199
3200
```

where **-d** stands for delimiter i.e '**space**' in this case denoted by ' '

However, awk comes pretty handy in such cases

```
**# awk '{print $2}' new.txt**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the position of the content in the first row at that column (3197) and then select the string at the same position in all rows with `awk`:

```
cat filename | awk -v field="3197" 'NR==1 {c = index($0,field)} {print substr($0,c,length(field))}'
```

*souce: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491770/20661*