# Exclude delimiters from sequence returned by bash cut command

Tags: bash, cut

I was surprised to find that the following cut command:

```
for n in {1..10}; do echo "[$(echo ' a    b c   de f ' | cut -d' ' -f$n)]"; done
```

returns:

```
[]
[a]
[]
[]
[]
[b]
[c]
[]
[]
[de]
```

While I could probably rig up an `awk` to get the desired (non-delimiters only) approach - is there a way to use `cut` itself in a little more intelligent manner?

I am looking for cut to output:

```
[a]
[b]
[c]
[de]
[f]
```

**Update**. I am getting answers providing **alternate** ways (not using `cut`) to do this. That is not the aim of this post. E.g. another way using `awk` is:

```
 echo "[$(echo ' a    b c   de f ' | awk -F' ' -f3)]"

 [c]
```

Comment: @BroSlow  Would that not allide the entire list into a single one?

Comment: You're right, misread the question

Comment: `cut` is useful for jobs, like parsing `/etc/passwd`, where the delimiter is a single unchanging character.  For this job,  `cut` is the wrong tool.

Comment: @John1024  Actually i'm inclined to accept your 'comment' as an answer. Feel free to add it as such.

Comment: @javadba OK.  Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` is an excellent tool for jobs *where the delimiter is a single unchanging character*.  The parsing of files like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are in this category.  Consider these lines from `/etc/passwd`:

```
sshd:x:103:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:104:106::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
```

Note that (1) The separator in these files is always colon, `:`, and never varies, and (2) two colons together mean that there is an empty field.  This is what `cut` was designed for.

By default, the separator that `cut` uses is a tab.  One can optionally change the separator to be a space.  But, there is no way to tell `cut` that the separator can be *either* a tab or a space.  There is also no way to tell cut to treat *repeated* separators as one.  Repeated separators are always interpreted as meaning empty fields.

When the separators don't fit the above requirements, `cut` is the wrong tool.

When field separators require more flexibility, `awk` or shell should be considered.  By default, awk accepts any sequence of whitespace as a field separator.  This can be customized, even to the point of having a regex for the field separator, by changing the `FS` variable.  The default for shell is also any sequence of any whitespace and this can be changed to other characters, but not regexes, using the `IFS` variable.

As an example, here is an awk solution:

```
$ echo ' a    b c   de f ' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "["$i"]"}'
[a]
[b]
[c]
[de]
[f]
```

#### Making shell and awk work together

To transfer a shell variable to awk, it is simplest to use a `-v` variable assignment.  For example, the following uses `-v` to assign the value of the `n` shell to an awk variable named `m`:

```
$ for n in {1..5}; do echo ' a    b c   de f ' | awk -v m=$n '{printf "[%s]\n", $m}'; done
[a]
[b]
[c]
[de]
[f]
```

Note that the awk code is all in single-quotes.  This means that the shell does not mess with it.  In the awk code, `$m` refers to the value of field number m.  `$m` has nothing to do with any shell variable or shell substitution.

Comment: i could not figure out the quotations nesting for doing that in awk. OOC I had been of the understanding that double quotes `"` nested inside of single quotes `'` ( but not the other way around) would be taken as literals and thus the $i variable would not be properly evaluated

Comment: @javadba Yes, that is correct: we do not want the shell to evaluate `$i`.  We want the shell to treat `$i` as a literal.  It is awk, __not__ the shell, that interprets the meaning of `$i`.  To awk, `$i` is the contents of field number `i` and `i` is an awk variable (a number).  Also, I added another example to the answer that shows how to pass shell variables into awk without complex quoting.

Comment: ah ok .  explains a long standing 'quarrel' i have had with awk.

Comment: you seem to know a something or other about this awk thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `cut` takes into account empty fields (and this is logical). If you have a string `"a~bb~~c"` (~ is a space), the 1st is `"a"`, the 2nd is `"bb"`, *the 3rd* is `""` and *the 4th* is `"c"`.

You might want to use `tr` beforehand as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476712/5050926).

```
for n in {1..10}; do echo "[$(echo ' a    b c   de f ' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f$n)]"; done
```

Comment: So the tr -s ' ' is interesting : it *does* allide the multiple instances of the delimiter.  But the array still has empty entries at the first and the last positions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your using cut in a for loop, but you can get the desired output in bash with just:

```
$ for i in ' a    b c   de f '; do printf "[%s]\n" $i  ; done
[a]
[b]
[c]
[de]
[f]
```

Comment: The loop is to show the results clearly for this post.

Comment: And the OP is specifically about how to use `cut`.  there are many other ways (including yours, awk, sed etc) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you expect (bash shell):

```
$ ar=(a b c de e)
$ for i in ${ar[@]}; do echo "[$i]"; done
[a]
[b]
[c]
[de]
[e]
```

Or :

```
for i in {a,b,c,de,f}; do echo "[$i]"; done
[a]
[b]
[c]
[de]
[f]
```

Using `cut` here feels not natural

Comment: The OP is specifically about how to use `cut`. there are many other ways (including yours, awk, sed etc) to do it