# Parse output of lastlog?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to withdraw the fourth field of the output of `lastlog -u 'user'` however using `cut -d' ' -f4` I can only withdraw the first field otherwise whitespace is output.

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
auser            pts/31   c-73-123-11-86.h Sun Jan 19 13:52:08 -0800 2014
```

I want to remove 'Sun Jan 19 13:52:08'. How can I do this considering there are multiple spaces in the line I want and using cut with specific subscript locations will produce erroneous results when usernames of different length are input. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See [How to make the 'cut' command treat several sequential delimiters as one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using any delimiter to separate `lastlog` output is problematic, since some of the fields *may* be empty:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lastlog -u ubuntu
Username         Port     From             Latest
ubuntu                                     **Never logged in**
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Alternatively you can just `cut` at the right number of characters, though this could be problematic too if the output ever changes in a new version:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lastlog -u ubuntu | { read; cut -c44- ;}
**Never logged in**
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Note the `read` simply reads and discards the first/header line of `lastlog` output.

Comment: With read, it will remove other records, if this user has several sessions.

Comment: @BMW - can you elaborate?  In this case, there is just one invocation of `read` - no while loops or anything.  So exactly one line will be read from stdin of the {} command grouping.  Then the remaining lines will be read by `cut`.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you are asking for

```
lastlog -u 'user' |  grep -v Latest | awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";print $0 }'
```

In your example, this will output

```
Sun Jan 19 13:52:08 -0800 2014
```

Comment: This works but the output Latest
   Sun Jan 19 13:52:08 -0800 2014 containts latest which is in the fourth column on the top. How could i modify to not grab latesT?

Comment: You could add a `grep -v Latest` or a `tail -n 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the length of the lines up to the string `Latest` and cut at that point:

```
$ lastlog -u $USER | (
    IFS= read -r line1
    IFS= read -r line2
    length=${#line1}
    echo "${line2::$((length - 6))}"
)
```

For my user this returns:

```
abcdef           tty1
```

(I don't have a "From" value for this user)