# How to use cut with multiple character delimiter in Unix?

Tags: sed, delimiter, cut

My file looks like this

```
abc ||| xyz ||| foo bar
hello world ||| spam ham jam ||| blah blah
```

I want to extract a specific column, e.g. I could have done:

```bash
sed 's/\s|||\s/\\t/g' file | cut -f1
```

But is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Is this what you look for? [How to make the 'cut' command treat several sequential delimiters as one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the 'cut' command treat same sequental delimiters as one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-same-sequental-delimiters-as-one)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since `|` is a valid regex expression, it needs to be escaped with `\\|` or put in square brackets: `[|]`.

You can do this:

```bash
awk -F' \\|\\|\\| ' '{print $1}' file
```

Some other variations that work as well:

```bash
awk -F' [|][|][|] ' '{print "$1"}' file
awk -F' [|]{3} ' '{print "$1"}' file
awk -F' \\|{3} ' '{print "$1"}' file
awk -F' \\|+ ' '{print "$1"}' file
awk -F' [|]+ ' '{print "$1"}' file
```

> `\` as separator does not work well in square brackets, only escaping, and many escape chars :)

```bash
cat file
abc \\\ xyz \\\ foo bar
```

Example: 4 `\` for every `\` in the expression, so 12 `\` in total.

```bash
awk -F' \\\\\\\\\\\\ ' '{print $2}' file
xyz
```

or

```bash
awk -F' \\\\{3} ' '{print $2}' file
xyz
```

or this but it's not much simpler

```bash
awk -F' [\\\\]{3} ' '{print $2}' file
xyz

awk -F' [\\\\][\\\\][\\\\] ' '{print $2}' file
xyz
```

Comment: Or just `{print $1}`?

Comment: A breakdown explaining how it works would be nice. Especially it'd be nice to specify that it's the `$1` that needs to be changed to get a different column.

Comment: The `$0` holds the entire line, so `$0=$1` replaces the line with the first field.  The `1` (anything that evaluates to true) after `{}` causes the line to be printed.

Comment: I had to do `awk -F ' \\|\\|\\| ' '{print $1}'`

Answer (score -2):

You can use awk to do it -

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=" \|\|\| ";}{print $1}' file
```

Replace $1 with $2, $3, etc.

Comment: Running this command, you get: `awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'