# Script to find network interface name from IPv6 address

Tags: bash, shell, ipv6

Experts,

Please help me to write a script to find the network interface name from the given IPv6 address.

For example:

```
if "ifconfig" gives the output like:

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:90440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:90440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:10181289 (10.1 MB)  TX bytes:10181289 (10.1 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:bb:9f:9d
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:febb:9f9d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:111:1111:1111:1000::41/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:138859 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46310896 (46.3 MB)  TX bytes:18119186 (18.1 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:bb:9f:9d
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:febb:9f9d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:222:2222:2222:1000::41/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:138859 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46310896 (46.3 MB)  TX bytes:18119186 (18.1 MB)
```

and the given IPv6 address is:  2001:111:1111:1111:1000::41
then the output should be "eth0"

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like this should be a very simple `awk` script. When you see the `Link` line you save the link name in a variable. Then when you match the address, you print the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make things complicated? I like simple. And this is about as simple as it gets. (And you shouldn't be using `ifconfig` as it's [deprecated](https://serverfault.com/q/458628/126632) and [not installed by default](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/700593) on modern Linux distributions.)

```
ip a s to fda8:75f3:eca7:100::1 | awk -F ": " 'NF > 1 {print $2}'
```

Let's go over it step by step.

First the `ip` output.

```
$ ip address show to fda8:75f3:eca7:100::1
12: virbr2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet6 fda8:75f3:eca7:100::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This tells us the interface the IP is on, and omits any other addresses that might be on the interface.

So we'll parse it out with `awk`. We use `": "` as a [field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25447324/1068283), print the second field, and [only print matching lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128328/20805).

```
$ ip address show to fda8:75f3:eca7:100::1 | awk -F ": " 'NF > 1 {print $2}'
virbr2
```

Finally we'll abbreviate `address show` to the minimum.

```
$ ip a s to fda8:75f3:eca7:100::1 | awk -F ": " 'NF > 1 {print $2}'
virbr2
```

This will also work with IPv4 addresses, if you want to locate one of those.

Comment: Thank you. This is generic for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: To be fair, the other answer probably works for IPv4 also, but he didn't mention it, and it certainly won't work when `ifconfig` isn't installed.

Comment: why `NF>1` instead of `NR==1`?

Comment: @AlexP. I suppose you could do it either way.