# Multicharacter delimiter cut

Tags: linux, bash

My file looks like:

```
19-04-05 08:45:22,643: INFO  [ByrioThread] [] kks.connectorLog: Very important information
```

I want to cut it using a two character delimiter ": ", but with field definition "field 2 and all next". This would be a cut command as:

```
cut -f2- -d': '
```

so the output would be:

```
INFO  [ByrioThread] [] kks.connectorLog: Very important information
```

however cut does not support multicharacter delimiter. Therefore answer given here  [How to use cut with multiple character delimiter? unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447324/how-to-use-cut-with-multiple-character-delimiter-unix) with awk does not work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output for this?

Comment: "cut does not support multicharacter delimiter" ... "Therefore answer ... with **awk** does not work." .. does not compute. Awk supports *regular expressions* as the field separator, it certainly supports multicharacter delimiters.  What `cut` supports has nothing to do with Awk.

Comment: If your numbers are zero padded, chances are that your information always start in the same column. In that case, don't try to cut on a field separator, just cut from a specific column: `cut -c24-`

Answer (score 2):

This `grep` might work for you:

```
grep -Po ': \K.*' file
```

---

Or a pure `bash` solution using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf '%s\n' "${line#*: }"
done < file
```

Comment: `\K` is always super handy! ;-) +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'awk' with a multi-character delimiter.

```
awk -F": " 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {$1=""; print $0}'  < input.txt | cut -c 3-
```

As you require your delimiter to appear in the output you'll need to set your output field separator (OFS), otherwise you'll have your delimiter replaced with a space.  This is done by `BEGIN {OFS=FS}`.  We're then dropping the first field with `$1=""` and then printing out what remains, having dropped the unnecessary field separator (with `cut`)

Alternatively, we can remove the first field and the field separator and do this directly with:

```
awk -F": " 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {sub($1 FS,"")}1' < input.txt
```

The removal is done by substituting the empty string for the first field and the field separator.  The additional `1` then triggers the printing of the remaining text.

Answer (score 1):

As the first part `19-04-05 08:45:22,643:` is always fixed in size, why don't you go for:

```
$ echo '19-04-05 08:45:22,643: INFO  [ByrioThread] [] kks.connectorLog: Very important information' | sed -E 's/^.{23}//'
INFO  [ByrioThread] [] kks.connectorLog: Very important information
```

Or via `grep`

```
grep -oP '(?<=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}: ).*'
```

or via `awk`

```
$ echo '19-04-05 08:45:22,643: INFO  [ByrioThread] [] kks.connectorLog: Very important information' | awk -F '\([0-9]{2}[:-] ?\)*,[0-9]{3}: ' '{print $2}'
INFO  [ByrioThread] [] kks.connectorLog: Very important information
```