# cut text file and get the first field bash

Tags: grep, sh, cut

i had a problem with using grep, or cut command to get out the files size 
i have that file :

```
   4096 Feb 15 21:52 f1
      0 Feb 15 18:24 f4
6928808 Feb 10 16:59 install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz
     87 Feb 14 18:43 sc1.sh
    281 Feb 14 19:11 sc2.sh
    168 Feb 14 21:40 sc3.sh
    345 Feb 15 21:15 sc4.sh
    278 Feb 15 19:27 sc4.sh~
      6 Feb 15 18:27 sc5.sh
    472 Feb 16 11:01 sc6.sh
    375 Feb 16 11:01 sc6.sh~
    359 Feb 17 01:18 sc7.sh
    358 Feb 17 01:17 sc7.sh~
    230 Feb 16 09:31 toUppefi.sh
    230 Feb 16 02:07 toUppefi.sh~
```

i need to get off only the first numbers every time for example :

```
4096
0
...
```

I used `ls -l .  | cut -d" " -f5` (for list of files!) to get only size but the result is spaces ! because of the space before numbers ! and when i use delimiter " " and -f it doesn't work it gives only the most biggest number that begin from the left side , i hope u understand my problem

Comment: If you want to get the first field of lines like these look at `awk`. That being said you don't want to [parse the output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the 'cut' command treat several sequential delimiters as one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `ls -l . | awk '{print $1}'`, but you should follow the general advice advice to avoid parsing the output of `ls`.

The usual way to avoid parsing the output of `ls` is to loop over the files to get the information you need. To get the size of the files, you could use `wc -c`.

```
for file in *; do
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then   #test if file exists to avoid problems with an empty directory
        wc -c "$file"
    fi
done
```

If you really only need the size - just pipe through awk.

```
for file in *; do
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then
        wc -c "$file" | awk '{print $1}'
    fi
done
```

Getting the size without using awk (@tripleee suggestion):

```
for file in *; do
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then
        wc -c < "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: thank u sir for ur reply , can't we do it with just using cut command ?

Comment: The other answers have good explanations of the problem of using `cut` in this case.

Comment: The answer which uses `stat` is closer to what `ls` does internally, and will return a size for directories, too. You can avoid Awk by doing ’wc -c <"$file"` with a redirection.

Comment: The `ls -l` column he wanted and `wc -c` give the same answer here. That's why I suggested it. So does `stat`, actually, but it doesn't have a `-c` flag here (like in one of the answers).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `cut` does not support patterns as delimiters, e.g. `[ \t]+`. This can be mitigated to some extent with `tr -s`, e.g. if all rows start with at least one space, this works:

```
tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

An alternative is to use `sed` to remove all whitespace from the start of line, e.g.:

```
sed 's/^ *//' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

On the other hand, to retrieve file sizes you are better of using `stat`:

```
stat -c '%s %n' *
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with  `cut` it that it can not use regex in delimiter.
So setting it to space and ask for first field you get only

```
ls -l . | cut -f 1 -d " "
6928808
```

But this `awk` we set line to first field  `$0=$1` and then print the line `1`:

```
ls -l . | awk '{$0=$1}1'
4096
0
6928808
87
281
168
345
278
6
472
375
359
358
230
230
```

Or you could do this: `ls -l . | awk '{print $1}'`