# How to avoid leading space using cut command?

Tags: cut

**Requirement:** I need to use only `grep`/`cut`/`join`.

I have data like:

```
  3 abcd
 23 xyz
1234 abc
```

I want to pipe this data to `cut` and then extract columns. But, when I am using `cut -d' ' -f 1,2` it treats each space as its own column divider. I would prefer the first two rows be trimmed prior to `cut`. Is there a way?

Example (I have used `tr` for demonstration purposes of where the spaces are here; it is not allowed in the solution):

```sh
$ echo '  3 abcd
23 xyz
1234 abc' | cut -d' ' -f 1,2 | tr ' ' '_'
_
_23
1234_abc
```

Expected output:

```sh
$3 abcd
23 xyz
1234 abc
```

Comment: Show what you tried as an [mcve], and the resulting output. For example, you should show the `-d` option you use in this context.

Comment: @jdv I have editted. Please have a look.

Comment: There was an answer that showed one potential way of massaging the input to remove the leading delimiters with "sed". If you need to preserve those leading delimiters then you have an extra challenge. There are other hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4143252/1531971 (though this talks about squeezing multiple delimiters to a single delimiter, the same tools can be used to massage leading delimiters with a little work.)

Comment: At the end, I wish to have only like 3 abcd, 23 xyz,1234 abc

Comment: Strip leading spaces before passing the args onto cut. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102008/156990

Comment: The only problem is that I am restricted to not use awk/sed. I can only use grep/cut/join

Comment: That is the sort of detail that SHOULD BE IN THE QUESTION.

Comment: I have already mentioned I need to use only cut/join

Comment: Well, and now you say grep as well. Which is it?

Comment: `grep -oe "[0-9]*[[:space:]]*[a-z]*$" < ~/data.txt | cut -f1,2 -d" "` is a start, but it will not handle multiple delimiters and may choke on trailing delimiters.

Comment: that is awesome. A great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just `grep`, you can accomplish this with the following pipe:

```
grep -oe "[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*$"

grep    # a tool for matching text
  -o    # only prints out matching text
  -e    # uses a regex
  [^ ]  # match anything that isn't a space
  *     # match zero or more of the previous element
  $     # the end of the line
```

*Note*: This does not account for trailing whitespace.

Demonstration:

```sh
$ echo '  3 abcd
 23 xyz
1234 abc' | grep -oe "[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*$"
3 abcd
23 xyz
1234 abc
```

Comment: can you explain that regex too