# Hierarchical Glacier object retrieval

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I would like to restore all objects inside an Amazon S3 bucket, which is now frozen in Glacier. These are my Folders inside the bucket:

`$ aws s3 ls s3://cogrehab
                           PRE baseline/
                           PRE codes/
                           PRE logs/
                           PRE tp1/
                           PRE tp2/
    2014-05-17 20:14:00         27 about.txt`

So according to another question here [How to restore folders (or entire buckets) to Amazon S3 from Glacier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033651/how-to-restore-folders-or-entire-buckets-to-amazon-s3-from-glacier) I proceed as follows:

```
aws s3 ls s3://cogrehab | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $4))}' | xargs -I %%% -L 1 aws     s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=90 --bucket cogrehab --key "%%%"`
```

But I get this error:

```
Unknown options: baseline/, PRE
xargs: aws: exited with status 255; aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a blog post on a ruby script that automates the process. here:

http://www.faun.me/2012/12/16/restoring-archived-files-from-amazon-glacier-using-ruby.html

In any case you should be aware of penalty fees for s3 retrieval from glacier which could be really high!