# How do I restore an entire S3 bucket from Glacier permanently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A while ago when the price difference between standard storage and glacier was closer to 10:1 than 3:1, I moved a couple of bucket completely to Glacier using a life-cycle policy. Admittedly, I hadn't investigated how to reverse that process permanently.

I know the documentation states that I would have to "use the copy operation to overwrite the object as a Standard or RRS object", but I guess I'm unclear what that looks like. Do I just copy and paste within that bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Restoration can only be done at the Object level, not Bucket or Folder. When an object is restored, it is a available in Amazon S3 for the period requested (eg 2 days), then reverts to only being in Glacier. You'll need to copy the objects out of the bucket during that time to keep a copy of them in S3.

The easiest method would be to use a utility to restore multiple Objects for you, eg:

- [How to restore whole directories from Glacier?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=435089)

Also, see Stackoverflow: [How to restore folders (or entire buckets) to Amazon S3 from Glacier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033651/how-to-restore-folders-or-entire-buckets-to-amazon-s3-from-glacier)

Comment: Cool. I ended up writing a couple scripts (using the Ruby SDK, which is pretty cool). One restored everything and one copied everything over to separate bucket. I'm now curious if I copied everything from the original bucket to the original bucket, whether that would result in standard storage for all the objects while saving me, the hassle of switching buckets. I may try that.