# How to restore object from s3 glaceir deep archive to standard storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Last month, I moved all objects from S3 standard class to S3 glacier deep archive.

Currently, I need to restore one object from the Glacier deep archive to standard storage.

Could anyone list down the steps to complete the above process using the AWS console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore folders (or entire buckets) to Amazon S3 from Glacier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033651/how-to-restore-folders-or-entire-buckets-to-amazon-s3-from-glacier)

Comment: You can find the steps in aws docs itself: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/restoring-objects.html