# Remove columns when line matches a condition

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I am trying to remov certain columns from a text file on lines that match a string, but then leave the rest of the lines untouched.

Say I have a file (thousand of lines in reality)

```
10 12 a
USA John TGCAGG
USA John TGCATG
5 2 b
CAN Tom TGCACG
CAN Tom TGCAAC
....
```

And I want to create a new file that removes the 2nd column in lines that contain TGCA but leaves all other lines intact.  I would like to see:

```
10 12 a
USA TGCAGG
USA TGCATG
5 2 b
CAN TGCACG
CAN TGCAAC
```

I can modify which columns print on lines that match using a regexp to start awk or sed, but I cant get the other lines (which are not modified) to print, or to preserve the order of those lines.

Do I need to use an if statement in awk? Tried using next but I dont think I have that right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say:

```
$ awk '/TGCA/ {$2=$3; NF--} 1' file
10 12 a
USA TGCAGG
USA TGCATG
5 2 b
CAN TGCACG
CAN TGCAAC
```

That is: when the line contains `TGCA`, replace the 2nd column with the 3rd and decrease the number of fields. That is, remove the 2nd column.

Comment: I dont quite follow  how NF was used here or how to set the desired numebr of fields...  What if there were 4 columns  and I wanted to keep 3 and 4 ?  Or lets say I wanted to keep columns 1 and 3 and 4 (but not 2)? Is there a more general way to do this (or explain the code) without reducing fields?

Comment: It is quite tricky to delete a column in awk. To prevent getting trailing spaces I would go for something like this: [how to remove the first two columns in a file using shell (awk, sed, whatever)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14715189/1983854)

Comment: So if you can afford to just decrease `NF` is it fine. If it has to be more complex, I would still do some kind of column movement and finally decrease `NF` anyway.

Comment: Ok. This will print fields 3 and 4 on lines that match TGCA:                       `awk '/TGCA/{print substr($0, index($0, $3))}'`  . But, only those lines are printed. Any idea how to get the other lines as well ?  Is the 1 at the end of the awk routine the important piece of code?

Comment: @LP_640 `1` stands for "True", so that it prints the line anyway. If you already printed it then you can foro example skip it with `next`: `awk '/TGCA/{print substr($0, index($0, $3)); next} 1'`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/TGCA/ s/\s\+\S*//' filename
```

This removes from lines that contain `TGCA` the first occurrence of one or more spaces followed by any number of non-spaces -- which is the second column and the space(s) preceding it.

For BSD sed, this has to be amended because it doesn't understand `\s` or `\S` (or `\+` -- it is a bit painful). In that case,

```
sed '/TGCA/ s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}[^[:space:]]*//' filename
```

does the same.