# Print rest of the fields in awk

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose we have this data file.

```
john 32 maketing executive
jack 41 chief technical officer
jim  27 developer
dela 33 assistant risk management officer
```

I want to print using `awk`

```
john maketing executive
jack chief technical officer
jim  developer
dela assistant risk management officer
```

I know it can be done using `for`.

```
awk '{printf $1;  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){printf " %s", $i} printf "\n"}' < file
```

Problem is its long and looks complex.

Is there any other short way to print *rest of the fields*.

Comment: A simple hack is to set $2 to "", then print $0 (all fields) -- though that would give you an extra delimiter for the empty field.

Comment: 3 years after, you helped me. But you should change "<NF" to "<=NF", if not you'll skip the very last field ;)

Comment: 3 years after that, I edited the question to change <NF to <=NF, to fix the bug @Koreth pointed out.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Set the field(s) you want to skip to blank:

```
awk '{$2 = ""; print $0;}' < file_name
```

Source: [Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961994/147021)

Comment: Does not clean up extra space, and using unneeded `print $0` that could be replaced by a simple `1`

Comment: @Jotne When I use `1` in-place of `print $0`, I don't get any output from awk. You sure they're equivalent?

Comment: @Alex Remove `print $0` and put `1` after the closing `}`.

Answer (score 9):

Reliably with GNU awk for gensub() when using the default FS:

```
$ gawk -v delNr=2 '{$0=gensub("^([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"delNr-1"})[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*","\\1","")}1' file
john maketing executive
jack chief technical officer
jim  developer
dela assistant risk management officer
```

With other awks, you need to use match() and substr() instead of gensub(). Note that the variable delNr above tells awk which field you want to delete:

```
$ gawk -v delNr=3 '{$0=gensub("^([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"delNr-1"})[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*","\\1","")}1' file
john 32 executive
jack 41 technical officer
jim  27
dela 33 risk management officer
```

Do not do this:

```
awk '{sub($2 OFS, "")}1'
```

as the same text that's in $2 might be at the end of $1, and/or $2 might contain RE metacharacters so there's a very good chance that you'll remove the wrong string that way.

Do not do this:

```
awk '{$2=""}1' file
```

as it adds an FS and will compress all other contiguous white space between fields into a single blank char each.

Do not do this:

```
awk '{$2="";sub("  "," ")}1' file
```

as it hasthe space-compression issue mentioned above and relies on a hard-coded FS of a single blank (the default, though, so maybe not so bad) but more importantly if there were spaces before $1 it would remove one of those instead of the space it's adding between $1 and $2.

One last thing worth mentioning is that in recent versions of gawk there is a new function named patsplit() which works like split() BUT in addition to creating an array of the fields, it also creates an array of the spaces between the fields. What that means is that you can manipulate fields and the spaces between then within the arrays so you don't have to worry about awk recompiling the record using OFS if you manipulate a field. Then you just have to print the fields you want from the arrays. See patsplit() in http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions for more info.

Comment: Looking at these complications one wonders whether awk is indeed the best tool for this job. e.g. if fields are delimited by pipe or comma then whole awk code needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Depends on your input. If you have single chars between fields then `cut` is better. If you have anything else then gawk+gensub() or sed (very similar syntactically) might be the best options. Both of those can run into problems when trying to describe the negation of multi-char REs so then you need to look at gawk+patsplit() or gawk+FPAT. No silver bullet unfortunately.

Comment: Great answer I wish I could +2 you. One problem is the code is much longer than `for` loop solution. f

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - correct but it preserves the original white space whereas the for loop you posted will not produce the output you specified. By the way, wrt that for loop you posted - never use printf with input data, e.g. `printf $1` as that will fail spectacularly if your input data contains printf formatting characters such as `%`. Always use `printf "%s",$1` for printing input data instead. Also to print a newline is just `print ""`, no need for `printf "\n"`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use simple awk like this:

```
awk '{$2=""}1' file
```

However this will have an extra OFS in your output that can be avoided by this awk

```
awk '{sub($2 OFS, "")}1' file
```

OR else by using this tr and cut combo:

**On Linux:**

```
tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d ' ' -f1,f3-
```

**On OSX:**

```
tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d ' ' -f1 -f3-
```

Comment: This should be `cut -d' ' -f1,3-`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Thanks but `cut -f1,3-` is not portable and isn't supported on my OSX.

Comment: Then the OSX `cut` is broken. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/cut.html) says that *The application shall ensure that the option-argument list (see options -b, -c, and -f below) is a comma-separated list [...]* and `-f -f` does break on my Linux with `coreutils-8.16` with the error message *cut: only one type of list may be specified*.

Comment: I will provide both options with my comments above. Though I would prefer `awk '{sub($2 OFS, "")}1' file` as a solution for this problem.

Comment: Your edit is not quite correct ;-) Is that why it did not work for you?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: No that was typo in my edit. I did try `cut -d ' ' -f1,f3-` and got `cut: [-cf] list: illegal list value` on OSX.

Comment: Your mistake is still there, it is `-f1,3-` and not `-f1,f3-`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `awk '{sub($2 OFS, "")}1'` since the same text that's in $2 might be at the end of $1, and/or $2 might contain RE metacharacters so there's a very good chance that you'll remove the wrong string that way.

Comment: @EdMorton: Valid point about regex. I somehow thought if `/str/` form isn't used in `sub` then its treated as literal text rather than as regex.

Comment: @anubhava - no, the only awk function that looks for strings rather than REs in another string is index().

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton So looks like there is no simple way to delete a field with trailing OFS. (`index`+`substr` is the only possible way I think)

Comment: @anubhava - correct there's no simple way but see my answer for a robust way.

Answer (score 4):

This removes filed #2 and cleans up the extra space.

```
awk '{$2="";sub("  "," ")}1' file
```

Comment: what does that extra `1` do here?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im The `1` evaluates to true which kicks in the default block (`{ print $0 }`).

Comment: Does not clean anything, but instead like all rewrites of existing fields do - it replaces `IFS` (one or more in a row) into a single `OFS`. E.g. that is one way to implement a 'normalize spaces' filter: `awk '{$1=$1}1'`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to just use sed to replace the first digits and space match:

`sed 's|[0-9]\+\s\+||' file`

Answer (score 0):

Approach using `awk` that would not require `gawk` or any state mutations:

```
awk '{print $1 " " substr($0, index($0, $3));}' datafile
```

**UPD**

solution that is a bit longer, but will stand up the case when $1 or $2 contains $3:

```
awk '{print $1 " " substr($0, length($1 $2) + 1);}' data
```

Or even more robust if you have custom field separator:

```
awk '{print $1 " " substr($0, length($1 FS $2 FS) + 1);}' data
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use altering $n. If you have more spaces in some part you want to keep, it will reduce to one.