# How to git list only the tracked directories?

Tags: git

Using `git list-files` gives me the directories and the files tracked within. Is there a command like:

```
git list-directories
```

or something similar that lists only the tracked non-empty non-recursive directory names?

Comment: Probably not. Git tracks files, not directories. You might be able to somehow derive that information from the `list-files` command though and define a git alias that does what you want.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Thanks, then I'll do that.

Comment: Cool. Once you figure it out be sure to post an answer here for the benefit of anyone else who might have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`git ls-files | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq`

Comment: I'd do a sed, `...|sed s,/[^/]*$,,|uniq`, avoiding `xargs -n 1` seems like a good rule of thumb to me.

Comment: @CDub : This gives out the subdirectories as well. Still useful though.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want subdirectories?

Comment: @CDub: I'm tracking directories that define simulation test cases. There are a lot of subdirectories. When the parameters I'm using to set up the tests differ strongly in numbers and values, I create another test and start tracking it with git, I don't have it defined as another version of the same directory in that case. Once the algorithm is up and running I need to decide which tests to keep, so I need to do some cleaning up: so I only want to list the top level directories to see if I am tracking all of them, or which ones are not tracked.

Comment: I believe that this misses directories that have no files, just other directories. Here is a method that considers them as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54162211/895245

Comment: this won't work if file names contain newlines. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: This solution shows the directories from the current directory downwards: You won't get all the directories in the tree if you're not at the top of the tree/repo (so `cd` there first if that's what you want), and also that some directory names may be repeated, fix that by including a `sort`, so `git ls-files | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 3):

```
git ls-tree -rt HEAD:./ | awk '{if ($2 == "tree") print $4;}'
```

If the files may contain spaces, we would have to play around with: [Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last) which is not very fun.

`-r` makes it recurse, and `-t` makes it print trees when recursing, which is turned off by default.

I was unable to use `ls-tree` as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247815/895245 because it is hard to deal with directories that have no files, just other directories.

This method also shows [empty trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/is-gits-semi-secret-empty-tree-object-reliable-and-why-is-there-not-a-symbolic).

Tested on Git 2.19.0.

Comment: This one worked for me `git ls-tree -rtd --format='%(path)' HEAD ./`

Answer (score 0):

The following command (leveraging `git ls-files`) returns all paths of directories **directly** containing committed or staged files.

This command can be executed **irrespective of the 'current working directory' it is executed in** (i.e., it can be executed in any subdirectory of this git repository, yet will always return paths including those from other subdirectories (instead of only returning paths of only the *current* *sub*directories<sup>(that being a characteristic/limitation/caveat/gotcha I noticed with other answers)</sup>)).

The returned paths are relative to this git repository's root directory.

```
git ls-files --full-name $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort --version-sort | uniq | grep --invert-match '^\.$'
```

Explanation:

- `git ls-files --full-name ...`: return *file* paths relative to "starting point".
- `... $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`: set the "starting point" to this git repository's root directory. This is important if you want to have all paths, and not only paths scoped to the current working directory this command is executed in.
- `xargs -n 1 dirname`: The previous pipe step has returned committed and staged *files*. This pipe step returns their containing *directory*.
- `sort --version-sort`: by default, `sort` sorts strings with dots (e.g. `.config/foo`) unexpectedly. The `--version-sort` option results in a more logical sorting.
- `uniq`: filter away duplicate entries.
- `grep --invert-match '^\.$'`: previous pipe steps created a line entry "`.`", signifying that there exists at least one committed or staged file directly in this git repository's root directory. This "`.`" entry may or may not be desirable. When not desired, this `grep` statement filters it away.

Example git repository (located within `/home/someuser/git/testrepository/`):

```
# committed files (listed with "git ls-files /home/someuser/git/testrepository/")
.config/foo.conf
.config/very/nested/deep.txt
README.md
a-directory/a1-file.txt
a-directory/a2-file.txt
z-directory/z-file.txt
z-directory/z-subdirectory/z-subfile.txt
```

Running aforementioned command from any contained (sub-)directory, e.g. from `/home/someuser/git/testrepository/.config/very/`:

```
$ cd /home/someuser/git/testrepository/.config/very/
$ git ls-files --full-name $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort --version-sort | uniq | grep --invert-match '^\.$'
.config
.config/very/nested
a-directory
z-directory
z-directory/z-subdirectory
```

Notice:

- `.config/very` is not present in the returned list. This is because there doesn't exist any file committed or staged **directly** in `.config/very/`.
- `.config/very/nested` is present in the returned list as it (directly) contains the committed file `.config/very/nested/deep.txt`.

#### Also returning paths from directories which don't have any committed files directly in them (but which contain subdirectories with committed files)

The following command (leveraging `git ls-tree`) will return **all** paths leading towards **committed** files, including intermediate directories. Different to the previous command, it will **not** include paths to directories which only contain staged-and-never-committed files:

```
git ls-tree -rt HEAD --name-only --full-tree | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort --version-sort | uniq | grep --invert-match '^\.$'
```

This is the output for the previously given example git repository:

```
$ cd /home/someuser/git/testrepository/.config/very/
$ git ls-tree -rt HEAD --name-only --full-tree | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort --version-sort | uniq | grep --invert-match '^\.$'
.config
.config/very
.config/very/nested
a-directory
z-directory
z-directory/z-subdirectory
```

Notice:

- With this command, `.config/very` *is* present in the returned list despite that directory not having a committed file **directly** in it. It is included because it leads towards a committed file (`.config/very/nested/deep.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

How about the following solution:

```
git ls-files | sed -e '/^[^/]*$/d' -e 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort -u
```