# manipulate first field and then print rest of the line for csv files using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have many csv file in which I need to manipulate the first field which contains the date and then print the rest of the line.
The files have varying field lengths.

My sample line is

```
"11.07.2016 00:00:00",DON1SOE02,PAPN,PAPN,OPEN1000,918945,
```

I have tried the code below

```
awk -F"," '{print "\""substr($1,08,4)"-"substr($1,5,2)"-"substr($1,2,2)substr(‌​$1,12,9)"\","$0""}' file.csv
```

The result of this is

```
"2016-07-11 00:00:00","11.07.2016 00:00:00",DON1SOE02,PAPN,PAPN,OPEN1000,918945,
```

Is there any way to avoid printing the unmodified date field, i.e. "11.07.2016 00:00:00"

solution below has a way to skip the first column, but I would like to modify the first column then print the modification and then skip printing unmodified first column

[Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must give the new value to your the first field: `awk '{$1="..."}1`. Otherwise the whole line `$0` will stay unchanged:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$1="\""substr($1,8,4)"-"substr($1,5,2)"-"substr($1,2,2)""substr($1,12,9)"\""}1' file.csv
```

Comment: @fedorqui: it's indeed more clear like this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution.