# How do I edit an existing tag message in Git?

Tags: git, git-tag

We have several annotated tags in our Git repository. The older tags have bogus messages that we would like to update to be in our new style.

```
% git tag -n1
v1.0 message
v1.1 message
v1.2 message
v2.0 Version 2.0 built on 15 October 2011.
```

In this example, we would like to make v1.x messages look like the v2.0 message. How would we do this?

Comment: Note: with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), a simple `git tag -m "A message" --edit v1.0` would be enough. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215146/6309)

Comment: Related: [How do you rename a Git tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/3357935)

Comment: @VonC Tried it and received `fatal: tag 'v6.6.2' already exists` using `2.17.0`.

Comment: You could always delete the previous tag and do it again.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

```sh
git tag <tag name> <tag name>^{} -f -m "<new message>"
```

This will create a new tag with the same name (by overwriting the original).

Comment: Does this maintain the original tag's date?

Comment: Answer to my own comment question: Yes, it _does_ change the date. :(

Comment: See the "On Backdating Tags" section in `git tag --help`.

Comment: It should also be noted that you can also append multiple messages (they get separated by a new line - on GitHub) `git tag <tag name> <tag name> -f -m "<new message>" -m "<new message>" -m "<new message>"`

Comment: After doing this, git show <tag name> shows both the original and the new messages, so some ref must still exist to the original tag. How do I locate/remove/gc the old tag ref ?

Comment: Are you certain it's not the tag and commit message your seeing?

Comment: Pretty sure. git log shows 2 tag objects: 
bash-4.1$ git show 9.03.050
 tag 9.03.050
Tagger: Testing <testing@testing.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 24 21:05:50 2014 -0500

v9.03.050
bash-4.1$ GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon Feb 24 21:05:50 2014 -0500" git tag 9.03.050 9.03.050 -f -m 9.03.050
Updated tag '9.03.050' (was d70cae7)
bash-4.1$ git show 9.03.050
tag 9.03.050
Tagger: Chris Morley <chris.morley@testing.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 24 21:05:50 2014 -0500

9.03.050

tag 9.03.050
Tagger: Testing Lebanon <testing-lebanon@cd-adapco.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 24 21:05:50 2014 -0500

v9.03.050
bash-4.1$

Comment: @ChrisMorley looks at my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/23532519/603949 - in short, use `<tag name>^{}` when you want to replace the `old tag`

Comment: To preserve the original date, based on @dahlbyk observation:

`git checkout SHA1_OF_COMMIT`
`GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show --format=%aD  | head -1)" git tag TAG_MODIFIED TAG_MODIFIED -f -m "New message for tag"`

Comment: **Warning**: This creates a duplicate tag that points to your old tag. See [Sungam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532519/3357935) for a safer solution.

Comment: And if the tag was pushed before editing its message, how do you push this edited tag?

Comment: The `<tag name>^{}` thing didn't work for me. After some searching I determined that [this is a Windows thing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects): `cmd.exe` uses `^` as a shell escape, so you need to double it up.

Comment: Please note that the idea of `^{}` edited in by Stevoisiak basically comes from [Sungam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532519/1536976).

Comment: @alondono push -f, but only if you know no one else has pulled already

Comment: Could it be done using a editor like emacs or nano?

Answer (score 121):

To update a complex message, just specify the annotated tag option with `-a` or the signed tag option with `-s`:

```
git tag <tag name> <tag name>^{} -f -a
```

This will open an editor **with the contents of your old tag message**.

Comment: The `<tag name>^{}` thing didn't work for me. After some searching I determined that [this is a Windows thing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects): `cmd.exe` uses `^` as a shell escape, so you need to double it up.

Comment: Please note that the idea of `^{}` edited in by John Kugelman basically comes from [Sungam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532519/1536976).

Answer (score 48):

`git tag <tag name> <tag name>^{} -f -a`

This is an improvement: without `^{}` it will create a new tag object that reference the old tag object, where both of them will have the same tag name.

`<tag name>^{}` will resolve the tag/reference until it finds the first commit hash.

Comment: @BrentFoust, that works only when your head is at the tagged commit

`usage: git tag [-a|-s|-u <key-id>] [-f] [-m <msg>|-F <file>] <tagname> [<head>]`

Comment: The `<tag name>^{}` thing didn't work for me. After some searching I determined that [this is a Windows thing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects): `cmd.exe` uses `^` as a shell escape, so you need to double it up.

Answer (score 45):

## TL;DR

You can do this by deleting your tag and recreating it while spoofing the date and author:

```
> git tag -d <tag-name>
> [GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=<original-commit-date>] \
> [GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=<original-author-name>] \
> git tag <tag-name> [commit]
```

## Whole story:

Building on [Sungram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532519/1864317)'s answer (originally proposed as an edit):

## 1. Accepted answer

This is an improvement over [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813236/1864317) and [Eric Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14130875/1864317)'s answers.
Their answers will create a new tag object that references the old tag object and both are going to have the same name.

To illustrate this, consider the following:

```
> git tag tag1 tag1 -f -a  # accepted answer
> git rev-list --objects -g --no-walk --all
[ example output: ]
6bdcc347fca041a5138f89fdf5276b3ebf9095d5
260ab7928d986472895b8c55e54569b3f3cb9517 tag1
a5797673f610914a45ef7ac051e3ee831a6e7c25 tag1
f22d6308c3cd330a3b0d86b9bf05562faf6b6f17

> git show tag1
tag tag1
Tagger: [tagger]
Date:   [date of updated tag]
[Updated description]

tag tag1
Tagger: [tagger]
Date:   [date of original tag]
[Original description]

[tagged commit details]
```

## 2. Sungram's improvement

Using `<tag name>^{}` as the second argument of `git tag` will instead delete all previous tags with the same name.

Consider the continuation of the previous terminal session:

```
> git tag tag1 tag1^{} -f -a  # suggested improvement
> git rev-list --objects -g --no-walk --all
[ example output: ]
6bdcc347fca041a5138f89fdf5276b3ebf9095d5
75f02acacfd7d91d55b5bcfdfb1f00aebeed15e3 tag1
f22d6308c3cd330a3b0d86b9bf05562faf6b6f17 

> git show tag1
tag tag1
Tagger: [tagger]
Date:   [date of updated tag]
[Updated description]

[tagged commit details]
```

## 3. Save the date

Lastly, if you want to keep the date of the original tag as the date of the updated tag, use some awk (or similar) magic or just paste the date you want instead. The following is a **substitute** for the second example (otherwise the original date would be lost due to overriding):

```
> GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show tag1 |                              # get info about the tag cascade including the date original of the original tag
> awk '{
>     if ($1 == "Date:") {
>         print substr($0, index($0,$3))
>     }
> }' |                                                               # extract all the dates from the info
> tail -2 | head -1)"                                               `# get the second to last date, as the last one is the commit date` \
> git tag tag1 tag1^{} -a -f                                         # finally, update the tag message, but save the date of the old one
>
> git rev-list --objects -g --no-walk --all
6bdcc347fca041a5138f89fdf5276b3ebf9095d5
e18c178f2a548b37799b100ab90ca785af1fede0 tag1
f22d6308c3cd330a3b0d86b9bf05562faf6b6f17
> git show tag1
tag tag1
Tagger: [tagger]
Date:   [date of original tag]
[Updated description]

[tagged commit details]
```

References:

- [SO: Quick listing objects in git database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350019/1864317)
- [SO: Change the committer date of a git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741848/1864317)
- [Awk: A tutorial and introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)
- [SO: Filter output by first-token-of-line and extract rest-of-line with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630921/1864317)
- [SO: How to put bash line comment in a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797512/1864317)

## 4. DIY

Alternatively to updating the tags, you can just delete them and create them again. As it turns out updating just adds a new tag and makes it point to the old one, or alternatively, just implicitly deletes the old one and creates a new one to point to the same commit anyway.

You can achieve this by issuing:

```
> git tag -d <tag-name>
> [GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=<original-commit-date>] \
> [GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=<original-author-name>] \
> git tag <tag-name> [commit]
```

Here `[optional]` is an optional field; `<required>` is a required field.
Of course, you can add any flags after the `git tag` command that you normally would.

Comment: [Quoting Andreas Schwab](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Should-GIT-AUTHOR-NAME-EMAIL-set-the-tagger-name-email-td7566159.html):

```The tagger is controlled by the committer info. 
(...)
GIT_COMMITTER_{NAME,EMAIL}.  A tagger isn't really an author.```

Answer (score 16):

@Andy's original solution from 2016 (which was eventually updated)

```
git tag <tag-name> <tag-name> -f -a
```

is **wrong**. After it, with

```
git show
```

command, we will see stack tags with same name.

It add a new tag with same tag name and new message at commit `<tag-name>`. But it don't remove old tag. It's a special case of this command:

```
git tag [<commit> | <old-tag>] <tag-name>
```

But just `<old-tag>` is same with `<tag-name>`.

---

Correct solution is simple, just update tag is OK.

```
git tag <tag-name> -f -a
```

Remember, only **ONE**  here.

If we want change tag, which isn't `HEAD`, we need an extra `<commit>` argument.

```
git tag <commit> <tag-name> -f -a
```

Comment: YES! You're right. Thanks for pointing that. After re-write the tag annotated a few times, I was check my tag with `git show <tag>` and I see all the previous editions.

Comment: The problem is: if I need update some tag which isn't `HEAD`, passing the extra `<commit>`, the tag opened is empty. I expected the old tag to just edit. Is there way?

Comment: Please note that Andy's solution has been updated since you answered. Perhaps it would be nice to start your answer with a message saying that it has been fixed? Also could it be that your command `git tag <commit> <tag-name> -f -a` has <commit> and <tag-name> reversed? It looks this way when comparing with other answers and the docs, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Having the same OP problem but need some completeness about it.
Ok, I have an old commit whose hash tag show differences when comparing with it's hash (strange, but true), so I checkout to the offending commit, which show me the "you are in detached HEAD" messahe, delete the old tag and creates the new one with the same name... Now, how I push this fix to the repo, being that it's not a new commit?

This final "push" is what I don't see commented in any of the excellent answers I'd read.

Comment: @FerB. You will have to use the -f option in your push command to force it.  Using -f in pushes is frowned upon.  So use if only if you know nobody else have pulled since your last push.

Answer (score 9):

> we would like to make v1.x messages look like the v2.0 message

With Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), there will be an alternative to creating a *new* tag with `git tag <tag name> <tag name> -f -m "<new message>"`, since "`git tag`" learned an **explicit "`--edit`" option** that allows the message given via "`-m`" and "`-F`" to be further edited.

See [commit 9eed6e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eed6e40c0ec9cbe89efd7303c3facd16fa1364f) (06 Feb 2018) by [Nicolas Morey-Chaisemartin (`nmorey`)](https://github.com/nmorey).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 05d290e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d290e1dbd2ed424cd3c872c5b20390100fa5f7), 06 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `tag`: add `--edit` option
>
> Add a `--edit` option which allows modifying the messages provided by `-m` or `-F`, the same way `git commit --edit` does.

Comment: Could you please provide a coherent example using `--edit` that addresses the OP?

Comment: @JoshHabdas actually, you need to add the -f option: --edit only allows for the message to be further edited.

Comment: Thanks. So if `-f` flag is added also then `--edit` will edit the message and modify the timestamp, right?

Comment: @JoshHabdas That is the idea, yes.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to tag again, using the `-f` force flag.

```
git tag v1.0 -f -m "actual message"
```

Comment: This solution supposes that the current git head is at version 1.0. This can mess things up if it isn't, as it changes the revision associated to version 1.0. Andy's solution avoids this pitfall.

Answer (score 5):

Using the answers above (especially [Sungam's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532519/1536976)), this is my alias one-liner for `.gitconfig`. Replaces existing tag and preserves the commit date.

```
[alias]
tm = "!sh -c 'f() { export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git log -1 --format=%ci $0); git tag -f -a $0 $0^{}; }; f '"
```

*Improvements?*

Comment: Also keeps the author:

    `tag-amend = "!sh -c 'f() { name=$(git log -1 --format=%an $0); email=$(git log -1 --format=%ae $0); date=$(git log -1 --format=%ci $0); GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=\"${name}\" GIT_COMMITTER    _NAME=\"${name}\" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=\"${email}\" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=\"${email}\" GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=\"${date}\" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"${date}\" git tag -f -a $0 $0^{}; }; f '"`

Comment: Just tried this.  Instead of giving the replacement tag the author and date info from the tag itself, it uses the info from the commit the tag points to.  This is not necessarily the same and, in fact, is not the same for our case most of the time.  We have a multi-repo infrastructure and use annotated tags in a 'core' repo to record info about pushes that span multiple repos. So, in core, the commit being pointed at might not even be part of the real push.  The info in the annotated tag should reflect the real pushes in the other repos.

Comment: @tanger See stackoverflow.com/a/63142048/3124256 for a way to get the tagger info instead.

Comment: @minterior: Tried your code, and got an  error: `foo: 1: GIT_COMMITTER: not found` (my tag is named `foo`). Using git 2.30.2 .

Answer (score 1):

This is how I updated successfully a tag's message number 54.4 with a "RAMDOM DESCRIPTION" in the Github tags page:

```
git tag "54.4" "54.4^{}" -f -m "RAMDOM DESCRIPTION"
git push origin main --tags -f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GUI like **smartgit** just

1. create the same tag again at the same position with the new message
2. choose "overwrite existing tag"
3. force-push the tag to the upstream repository

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set of aliases that should do it for you based on the existing answers (especially [stanm's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019547/3124256)) here:

```
# Edit an existing tag, preserving the date and tagger
tag-amend = "!f() { : git tag ;\
    eval \"`git x-tag-environment-string`\";\
    git tag -a -f --edit -m \"$(git x-tag-message \"$1\")\" \"$1\" \"$1^{}\" \"${@:2}\";\
}; f"

# Rewrite an existing tag, preserving the date and tagger (accepts -m and -F)
tag-rewrite = "!f() { : git tag ;\
    eval \"`git x-tag-environment-string`\";\
    git tag -a -f \"$1\" \"$1^{}\" \"${@:2}\";\
}; f"

# Helpers to Extract the Tag Data
x-tag-data = tag -l --format
x-tag-message = x-tag-data '%(contents)'
x-tagger-name = x-tag-data '%(taggername)'
x-tagger-email = x-tag-data '%(taggeremail)'
x-tag-date = x-tag-data '%(taggerdate:rfc2822)'
x-tag-environment-string = "!f() { echo '\
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=${GIT_COMMITTER_DATE-`git x-tag-date \"$1\"`};\
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME-`git x-tagger-name \"$1\"`};\
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL-`git x-tagger-email \"$1\"`};\
';}; f"
```

These aliases accept a single tag name and any other flags to git tag and can be modified to support name changes pretty easily as well.

### Usage:

```
# opens editor to edit existing message
git tag-amend <tag name>

# add a new paragraph to the existing message
git tag-amend <tag name> -m "<new paragraph>"

# replace the message with a new one
git tag-rewrite <tag name> -m "<new message>"
```

### Support for light-weight tags

Use `creatordate`, `creatorname`, and `creatoremail` instead of the `tagger...` variants.  The `creator...` shortcuts will use `tagger...` if it exists and fallback to `committer...`.

Comment: Beware of possible quoting issues.  I'll be posting an edit that makes this more robust soon, but basically it comes down to using `for-each-ref --shell` rather than `tag -l` and letting git take care of the quoting.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with git 2.30.2 . Am getting: `f() { : git tag ;    eval "`git x-tag-environment-string`";    git tag -a -f --edit -m "$(git x-tag-message "$1")" "$1" "$1^{}" "${@:2}";}; f: 1: Bad substitution`

Comment: As I said, it has some quoting issues.  Will update when I have time to look at it again :)  See comment above for how to fix it; edits welcome!