# How can I change the commit pointed to by a signed tag?

Tags: git

Specifically, while retaining the tag's annotation message and date.

Last night, I created a signed tag for a repo I'm working on.  A few minutes later, I unthinkingly amended the commit I'd tagged.  Now, I'm getting ready to push my changes and need to clean up that tag before I do.

Looking at a [similar (ish) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019547/46387), I've attempted various combinations of `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITER_DATE` with no luck:

```
$ git show v0.1.1 | awk '{ if ($1 == "Date:") { print substr($0, index($0, $3)) } }'
Nov 26 18:14:17 2017 -0800
Nov 26 18:13:21 2017 -0800

$ git tag -d v0.1.1
Deleted tag 'v0.1.1' (was d4189a2)

$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Nov 26 18:14:17 2017 -0800" \
> GIT_COMMITER_DATE="Nov 26 18:14:17 2017 -0800" \
> git tag v0.1.1 9aa951c -s -m 'Display in columns.'

$ git show v0.1.1 | awk '{ if ($1 == "Date:") { print substr($0, index($0, $3)) } }'
Nov 27 13:34:16 2017 -0800
Nov 26 21:18:34 2017 -0800
```

How can I "fix" this tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly there: you're making a new signed, annotated tag.  You just have a typo:

> ```
> GIT_COMMITER_DATE="Nov 26 18:14:17 2017 -0800" \
> ```

This should read:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Nov 26 18:14:17 2017 -0800" \
```

(two T's in "committer").  But there's no obvious reason to force the tag time stamp back, since you're already making a new and different tag: you might as well just make a new signed tag with today's time-stamp.

#### Discussion

You *must* make a new signed tag (using, if you like, very similar contents and perhaps even the same tag-name, although before you re-use a tag name, you should read [the documentation discussion on the topic](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging)).  The issue here is that the signature is itself a cryptographic assertion about the tag's content, including the tag message *and the commit hash of the target of the tag*.  This means that in the new signed tag, you must have a different signature.

Since it *is* a new and different tag, if there's a chance that anyone else has the old tag, it's wisest to just give the new tag a new name (see linked discussion).  If there's no such chance, you can simply overwrite the old tag with `-f`.  The special Git environment variables can be used to override the default timestamps.

Comment: Good heavens, thwarted by a simple typo!  Fortunately, this tag hasn't ever made it off my local dev box (I wanted to fix it, first), so I have no concerns there.  As for my insistence on maintaining the original commit date, that's just to satisfy my near-obsession with bookkeeping!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my tests, the syntax you used doesn't make the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` variable visible to the subsequent `git` command.  I had better luck with

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=...
```

which of course you'd then want to un-set after running git.  There may be other shorthand ways; this is just what worked for me.

Also make sure you're using a recognized date format.  `"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"` worked for me.

By the way, I don't think "author date" matters; AFAIK (and as far as the docs indicate) a tag would only worry about one date.  In your output, the 2nd date is coming from the underlying commit (as you can see from the unprocessed `show` output).

So all of that said, one question... why?  If the amended commit was done "unthinkingly", why not use the reflog to back it out and commit your other changes as a separate commit?  Or, why is it a big deal that the tag date be retroactive anyway?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about author date, but was just throwing things at the wall to see what would stick at that point.  I was, however, able to get it working (sans typo) with that command syntax and date format on bash 3.1.23 and git 2.5.0; I suppose I should have put those version numbers in my question!

Comment: @BenBlank: Git's "approxidate" routine is pretty forgiving on inputs (with possibly hilariously wrong results without warning), but in general it should always take its own output as input.