# how to push tag message edits to origin?

Tags: git, gitlab

I made a spelling error on a tag message I pushed to the origin which I wanted to correct, but I am struggling to work out how to do it.

I edited the annotated tag message on my local branch successfully, using this page: [How do I edit an existing tag message in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813194/how-do-i-edit-an-existing-tag-message-in-git)

```
git tag <tag name> <tag name>^{} -f -m "<new message>"
```

this corrected the tag locally but I couldn't push the tag to the remote:

```
git push origin <tag name>
```

gave me an error

```
! [rejected]        v1.7 -> v1.7 (already exists)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:tompkins/vectri.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
```

So I tried to simply delete the tag and start again. I deleted it locally and recreated it, but when I tried to use this page [How to delete a remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-tag) to delete it remotely:

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```

I received the error:

```
remote: GitLab: You cannot delete a tag
```

is it possible to edit remote tag messages?

Comment: It seems you don't have the right to update a tag. You could ask the repository owner for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do:

```
git push origin -f <tag-name>
```

Comment: that did the trick, I needed to force. thanks. I also noticed that I could log on gitlab and delete the tag with my browser...

Comment: Make sure you tell (verbally, perhaps) everyone who picked up the *wrong* tag to *delete their copy* of the wrong tag, too.

Comment: *Always* be extraordinarily careful when using `git push --force` or `git push -f` on any branch where you are working with other people because it can destroy work and severely annoy your collaborators. Reserve it for times you accidentally push a commit with a password or other sensitive data.