# how to list files in Unix without the modified date

Tags: unix, ls

I'm trying to create a zip file that will run on multiple servers to compare the contents of the servers.  For many reasons, the easiest and best piece of information for me to compare is a text file of the directory listings... but I need that without the modified date as they make the comparisons show differences that don't matter in this case.

So if I run command `ls -la` to create text output for comparing, I get would get something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root   root       4096 Mar 20 14:59 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root   root       4096 Feb 18 03:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  9  web   ad         4096 Oct 30 14:35 apache-tomcat-6.0.18
drwxr-xr-x.  9  web   ad         4096 Mar 24 03:00 apache-tomcat-6.0.36
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root          5 Oct 30 14:06 java -> java6
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root         16 Oct 30 14:05 java6 -> jdk/jdk1.6.0_37/
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root         16 Mar 20 14:59 java7 -> jdk/jdk1.7.0_17/
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root       4096 Mar 20 15:02 jdk
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root         21 Nov  6 15:09 tomcat -> apache-tomcat-6.0.36/
```

What I would like is to use is `ls -la | cut -c 1-31` but that only takes one list (the characters 1-31) and I really want the data after the date.  I'm fairly new with Unix and was curious if anyone knows how to produce a list that would look something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root   root       4096 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root   root       4096 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  9  web   ad         4096 apache-tomcat-6.0.18
drwxr-xr-x.  9  web   ad         4096 apache-tomcat-6.0.36
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root          5 java -> java6
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root         16 java6 -> jdk/jdk1.6.0_37/
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root         16 java7 -> jdk/jdk1.7.0_17/
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root       4096 jdk
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root         21 tomcat -> apache-tomcat-6.0.36/
```

Thanks

Comment: You could filter the output of `ls`, but that can be unreliable, since `ls` output isn't really designed to be machine-readable. If you have GNU `find`, the `-printf` option lets you selectively print information in just about any format you like.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the best solution to your problem is to use awk.

```
ls -la | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $9}'
```

So you obtain an output like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 ..
drwx------+ 5 user staff 170 Desktop
drwx------+ 16 user staff 544 Documents
drwx------+ 6 user staff 204 Downloads
```

Comment: this works great!  Thanks.  I always knew I needed to expand my knowledge into awk.  Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately this will fail on files with spaces in names like 'moar bad;' --  
ls -ld moar\ bad\;  | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $9}'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 moar   
Another possible solution: ls -ld  --time-style='+' .  use time-style with null formatting

Answer (score 24):

Posting an alternate solution because the accepted one will fail on filename with spaces.

On Linux and other systems that support it (not macOS) use --time-style with null formatting

```
$ ls -lh
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  6 12:42 '$#%bad'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2 Jan  6 16:12 'moar bad;'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  6 12:40 'quote"file'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  6 12:41 'single'\''quote'\''file'

$ ls -lh  --time-style='+'
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0  '$#%bad'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2  'moar bad;'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0  'quote"file'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0  'single'\''quote'\''file'
```

Answer (score -1):

`cut` let's you specify ranges, [more easily than awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602035/how-to-print-third-column-to-last-column).
Use it in combination with `tr -s ' '` to trim repeating whitespaces.

```sh
$ ls -la /etc/ |tr -s ' ' |cut -d' ' -f1,2,3,4,5,9-
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 opt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 os-release -> ../usr/lib/os-release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6920 overlayroot.conf
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 vmware-tools
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 vtrgb -> /etc/alternatives/vtrgb
```

This is useful e.g. when using a parallel shell and you want to check files on multiple hosts, created at different times.